# Why does a custom UIButton image does not resize in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, interface-builder

Why does a custom UIButton image not resize with the button?

I set its view mode to *Scale to Fill* in Interface Builder, but unlike a UIImageView image, it doesn't respect that setting.

Am I looking in the wrong place or is it not possible?

Comment: I found that though it doesn't scale the image in IB it does scale  the image in runtime.

Comment: that's not necessarily true... if you have 80x80pixel img with a 60x60 pixel button, it will scale the button to match the image size whereas a lot of people want the opposite (scale the image to match the smaller button size)... see my reply to this post for proper code to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage/2890200#2890200

Answer (score 98, accepted):

While this may not be quite what you're after - the background image **does** scale.

Comment: If I put the image in the background, I get the correct behavior so you solved it, thanks.

Comment: If you are unwilling to use the background image (because say you want to use different images for different states), you need set the alignment property.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957317/how-do-i-scale-a-uibuttons-imageview/8179900#8179900

Comment: what if you want it to scale to fit? then background image, which scales to fill, would not be appropriate

Comment: ah, so not the image, but the *background image.* I will forget my name before forgetting this.

Answer (score 73):

Try this:

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
```

**In Swift:**

```
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
```

Comment: You saved my day! Bravo .. Also make sure button type is `custom`

Comment: Worked for me - XCode 8, Swift 3, UIButton created by storyboard, vector/PDF image as button image

Comment: This should be the accepted answer – setting the image as background gives a different behavior. E.g., it doesn't let you control the touch area (which, in case of a content image can be bigger than the image itself).

Answer (score 61):

Remember to set Control Alignment settings for the button

[image: here set Control Alignment settings for the button]

Answer (score 32):

Inside **Attribute Inspector** first set Type "`Custom`" and Style "`Default`" then Set alignment Horizontal and Vertical both "`fill`".

[image]

Comment: This answer helped me today

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2022, none of the other answers work correctly anymore.

Comment: Also confirming this worked in 2023.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old, but I think that the correct answer is that you should set the content mode to the "hidden" UIImageView that is inside the UIButton:

```
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

This will change the content mode for the images views of the images set with:

```
[button setImage:yourAwesomeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
//Or any other state
```

Comment: doesn't work for me :-( My images are still not stretched to fill the button width and height

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS8. Tried setting it before and after adding image to button. `self.button1.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;` Tried scaleAscpetFill and scaleToFill, no go. Cao Huu Loc's solution does work.

Answer (score 11):

Just do (From Design OR From Code):

#### From Design

1. Open your xib OR Storyboard.
2. Select button
3. Inside **Attribute Inspector** (Right side) > In **"Control"** section > select last **4th option** for both Horizontal and Verical.

[For Point#3: Change Horizontal and vertical Align to UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill and UIControlContentVericalAlignmentFill]

#### From Code

button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
button.contentVerticalAlignment =  UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;

Comment: Funny, in the XIB viewer it doesn't look scaled.  In fact it blows up the button to a larger size, but then at run-time it's scaled to the size it ought to be.

Answer (score 10):

**Interface Builder**

To get images in UIButtons to scale the same way as UIViews in interface Builder follow these steps:

Select your UIButton and from the **Identity Inspector** add the following to User **Defined Runtime Attributes**:

imageView.contentMode    Number    1

Where number is the enum number of contentMode, eg:

```
0 = Scale to fill 
1 = Aspect Fit 
2 = Aspect Fill
etc..
```

Then open the **Attributes** editor for your UIButton and under **Control** set the **Alignment** to Fill (last button on right) for both horizontal and vertical.

**SWIFT 3**

Note you can also do this in code with the following:

```
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Updating this post will full answer for Swift 5:

```
//Set button's image
let image = UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill") //Your image here
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)

//Optional: Remove background image if you added one on accident
button.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)

//Optional: Set button's title (displayed next to button's image)
button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)

//The button's "content" includes the title label and image
//So we set the button's content to fill the button
//If title label is nil, the content will only show the image
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill

//Set button's image to desired content mode (aspectFit avoids distortion)
//This restricts the image from resizing to fill the entire content area
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: `button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill` does the job, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Clip subviews property in Interface Builder to true.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Alas, that did not. Thanks for trying to help, though.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I found so far in Swift 2.1 is the following:

```
self.imageButton.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
self.imageButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

This will scale the image so it has an aspect fit in the imageView.

Answer (score -6):

Just get a real UIimageview and place a UIbutton on top of it and via layout menu set it to back. Then you can scale your image properly.