# How do I scale a UIButton's imageView?

Tags: ios, uibutton, scale

I created a UIButton instance named "button" with an image using `[UIButton setImage:forState:]`. The button.frame is larger than the image's size.

Now I want to scale this button's image smaller. I tried changing `button.imageView.frame`, `button.imageView.bounds` and `button.imageView.contentMode`, but all seem ineffective.

Can anyone help me scale a `UIButton`'s imageView?

I created the `UIButton` like this:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I tried to scale the image like this:

```
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
button.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70);
```

and this:

```
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
button.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70);
```

Answer (score 94):

For the original poster, here is the solution I found:

```
commentButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
```

This will allow your button to scale horizontally.  There is a vertical setting as well.

Took me several hours to figure that one out (the naming of the property is *very* unintuitive) so figured I'd share.

Comment: good sugggestion! my problem was on scaling stretched image to change size of leftbaritem button depends of its title.

Comment: This works but will not draw outside the bounds, think of it like aligning text in a line that you won't have anything pass the margins. So, you won't get the effect like UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill (with some part of the image cropped) from this one.

Answer (score 68):

I'd faced similar problem, where I've a background Image (one with border) and an image (flag) for a custom button. I wanted flag to be scaled down and in center. I tried changing imageView's attribute but didn't succeed and was seeing this image     --

[image]

During my experiments, I tried :

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(kTop,kLeft,kBottom,kRight)
```

I achieved expected result as :

[image]

Answer (score 48):

An Addition Way for config in XIB file.
You can choose this option if you want text or image is Scale full fill in UIButton.
It's will be the same with code.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton new];

btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
btn.contentVerticalAlignment   = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to stretch image for UIButton is perfectly then You can use more support of image asset and Slicing this image.    https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html

Comment: Wasn't even aware of this method. Rock on

Answer (score 25):

use

```
button.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

not

```
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Update:

As @Chris commented,

> To get this to work for setImage:forState:, you need to do the following to scale horizontally: myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;

Comment: This works great in combination with [button setBackgroundImage:forState:]. Thanks.

Comment: Note exactly what Jason said and you'll be good. It _doesn't_ work for setImage:forState:

Comment: To get this to work for setImage:forState:, you need to do the following to scale horizontally: myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;

Answer (score 15):

```
    UIButton *button= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,70,70)];
    button.buttonType = UIButtonTypeCustom;
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    UIImage *stretchableButtonImage = [buttonImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0]; 
    [button setBackgroundImage:stretchableButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: @EEE Thank you.But there are 2 problem: 

1. My question is use the UIButton's _imageView variable, not the _backgroundView variable. Have I to do it with backgroundView? 
2. the function [UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:] can only to make image larger, but can't make image smaller. 

Thanks all the same, and your answer solves my another question:I want to draw a title on the button with the image behind. I think the _backgroundImage can help me. 

Does this question has other better answer?

Comment: I see what you are trying to do and this is the way. if your image is bigger, then resize it using a tool, and everything you want to do will be done. Don't waste your time with_imageview. By the way if you like this asnwer, you can vote it up, and accept it

Comment: You can resize your image in Preview program in MacOS. Just open the image and selet tools-->Adjustsize

Comment: @EEE Yes,I can resize my image use a tool. But in my application sometimes I need the bigger image too, I don't want to two similar images only difference at size, that too waste space. And another way to do solve my question is that I can use CGBitmapContext to get a smaller image, but I guess this way is inconvenience compara to using _imageview.

The reason I did not vote it up is my reputation is less than 15, actually I really want to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I found this solution.

1) Subclass the following methods of `UIButton`

```
+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType {
    MyButton *toReturn = [super buttonWithType:buttonType];
    toReturn.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    return toReturn;
}

- (CGRect)imageRectForContentRect:(CGRect)contentRect {
    return contentRect;
}
```

And it works well.

Comment: - (CGRect) backgroundRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds, for the background image.

Answer (score 9):

Strange, the only combo that worked for me (iOS 5.1) is...

`button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

and

`[button setImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Originally I used: button.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; now I also need to write button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; to keep aspect ratio on iPad 3 retina

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this same problem, and there's a possible answer in this question:

[Why does a custom UIButton image does not resize in Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063019/why-does-a-custom-uibutton-image-does-not-resize-in-interface-builder)

Essentially, use the backgroundimage property instead, which does get scaled.

Answer (score 8):

Just do (From Design OR From Code):

#### From Design

1. Open your xib OR Storyboard.
2. Select button
3. Inside **Attribute Inspector** (Right side) > In **"Control"** section > select last **4th option** for both Horizontal and Verical.

[For Point#3: Change Horizontal and vertical Align to `UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill and UIControlContentVericalAlignmentFill]`

#### From Code

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
button.contentVerticalAlignment =  UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
```

Answer (score 5):

like this can solve your problem:

```
+ (UIImage*)resizedImage:(UIImage*)image
{
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size);
 [image drawInRect:frame];
 UIImage* resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 return resizedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From small test I just did after reading here, depends if you use setImage or setBackgroundImage, both did the same result and strech the image

```
//for setBackgroundImage
 self.imageButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        [self.imageButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgFileName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//for setImage
 self.imageButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
        self.imageButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
    [self.imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgFileName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: thanks a ton... perfect solution for fitting small image of size lesser then button size...

Answer (score 5):

## Storyboard

You must define specific property in **Runtime Attributes** of **Identity inspector** – `imageView.contentModel`, where you set value relatively to `rawValue` position of enum `UIViewContentMode`. 1 means **scaleAspectFit**.

[image: Set button.imageView.contentMode in Storyboard]

And button's alignment, in **Attributes inspector**:

[image: Full alignment of button]

Answer (score 4):

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
button.contentVerticalAlignment =  UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will also work, as the backgroundImage automatically scales

`[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can help to somebody else:

**Swift 3+**

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.fill
button.contentVerticalAlignment =  UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.fill
```

Answer (score 2):

from @JosephH

`contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControl.ContentHorizontalAlignment.fill contentVerticalAlignment =  UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.fill`

Answer (score 1):

I can't get a solution use by _imageView, but I can use a `CGContextRef` to solve it. It use the `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` to get the currentContextRef and draw a image in currentContextRef, and then scale or rotate the image and create a new image. But it's not perfect.

the code:

```
-(UIImage*) scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage*)photoimage width:(CGFloat)bounds_width height:(CGFloat)bounds_height;
{
    CGImageRef imgRef = photoimage.CGImage;

    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    bounds.size.width = bounds_width;
    bounds.size.height = bounds_height;

    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
    CGFloat scaleRatioheight = bounds.size.height / height;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
    CGFloat boundHeight;
    UIImageOrientation orient = photoimage.imageOrientation;
    switch(orient)
    {
        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid?image?orientation"];
            break;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft)
    {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatioheight);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatioheight);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return imageCopy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot in XCode 8]

At the bottom left of screenshot, you can see Stretching properties. Try using those.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify imageView by using custom class of UIButton. Please see my answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59874762/5693826

Answer (score 0):

Piggy backing off of another answer from 2020, I couldn't get the image to resize with the button. But this solved it :)
Go ahead and set these properties in the init() (or wherever) for your button.

```
self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
self.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
```

[Top button has those properties as .fill, bottom has default of .center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsrzN.png)

Answer (score -1):

Every UIButton has one hidden UIImageView of its own. So we have to set the content mode like the way given below...

```
[[btn imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```