# changing the text on the button on clicking in ios using swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

**Scenario:**

i have `VC` in which i have horizontally place **4 UIButton** and **4 UIImageView** attached to them, each button has their own individual view controllers every time they are pressed they display a respective `VC`.

**Issue:**

- The problem is I have to change the text color and the image color that I have used on clicking the button.
- Is it possible that i can use single button that has the image also text?
- how to change the fonts of the button on being click.

**Image :**

[image: These are the 4 buttons i made them like i place image view and a button]

Comment: Can you Show your code?

Comment: i will try to show

Comment: if you want to change VC on click then why you need to change the color of button?

Comment: take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954880/left-align-image-and-center-text-on-uibutton

Comment: it is not about alignment @hm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can subclass a `UIButton` to create your own button. Ultimately a button is inherited from `UIView` and thus, you can simply subclass and add any style, that you want to be added to a button. Subclassing a `UIButton` will give you absolute freedom in terms of design. You can also use API functions to set the image/text of the button, as shown in below

   `button.setImage(UIImage(named: "<image placeholder>") for: .normal)`

   Please note that the `.normal` is the state of the button and any changes to `normal` state gets applied to all other states of the button. If you wish to make changes to a specific state, you should mention that.
2. We attach a selector to the touch events of a button. The selector gets called when an event (like touchupinside aka click) occurs. In this selector you can write code for new font of the button. You can set the font as below

   `myButton.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: YourfontName, size: 20)`

Comment: i have button actions and outlet. what next should i do? i am new to ios and swift has been 2 months to me. so can you explain little simple terms. i have been stucked here since 7 days.

Comment: In the function that gets called "on-click" of the button - you can simply mention the changes that you want to see in the button.

Comment: @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "img1.jpg") for: .normal)
btn.titleLabel?.text =  "Text"
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use both text and image in UIButton like below

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageName") for: .normal)
button.setTitle("Title", for: .normal)
```

Use contentHorizontalAlignment of UIButton to set button title to the left or right of the image.

Use imageEdgeInsets and contentEdgeInsets of UIButton to set margin

Use IBAction of UIButton to change the image, title and font of the button on click

Use .highlighted state of UIButton to set image and title in highlighted state of UIButton

Answer (score 0):

of course, you can use a button, because we can set the image and text for a button.

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageName") for: .normal)
button.setTitle("the title string", for: .normal)
```

And button text font:

```
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "font string you want", size: 18)
```

Highlighted status color:

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .highlighted)
```

with Objective-C you can exchange the image and the text position in the button :

```
_titleViewBtn.size=CGSizeMake(100, 20);

CGFloat imgX=_titleViewBtn.imageView.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat titleX=_titleViewBtn.titleLabel.frame.origin.x;
if (imgX<titleX) {
    CGRect titleFrame=_titleViewBtn.titleLabel.frame;
    titleFrame.origin.x=imgX;
    _titleViewBtn.titleLabel.frame=titleFrame;

    CGRect imgFrame=_titleViewBtn.imageView.frame;
    imgFrame.origin.x=CGRectGetMaxX(_titleViewBtn.titleLabel.frame);
    _titleViewBtn.imageView.frame=imgFrame;

}
```

Comment: are you seen this `it possible that i can use single button that has the image also text?`

Comment: create the button array and touch up inside remove the all selection and add the sender to the corresponding value, thats all

Comment: yes i want to use the image and text in the same button. how to do that?

Comment: @SabaZehra you mean an image and text in one button, but you still have 4 button?

Answer (score 0):

You can set
`button.setImage(image: UIImage(named: "abc"), for: .normal)`
 
`button.setTitle(image: "abc", for: .normal)`

You change state action button ".normal" is state other.

Answer (score 0):

so guys here is the best solution :

Q1) The problem is I have to change the text color and the image color that 
     I have used on clicking the button.
A) a. drag and drop a button to the VC
   b. in ATTRIBUTES INSPECTOR by default the state is default choose the 
     color you want i choose grey and now click on the arrow in the side of 
     default and choose SELECTED state and choose the color and image for 
      that in the image put the image.png.
   c. go to the SIZE INSPECTOR and adjust the size of the image and text of 
      the button .
    d. go to you respected swift file and create each buttons iboutlet and 
       ibaction , in the action of each button use the following lines:

```
   button1.isselected = true
   button2.isselected = false
```

it worked for me.

Q2)Is it possible that i can use single button that has the image also text?

A) yes steps are above

Q3)how to change the fonts of the button on being click.
A) still working