# Set uibutton imageView size

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I have UIButton, on which I have title and image. I've set the imageView contentMode to scaleAspectFit so that the image is seen in normal ratio, but the imageView stays the same. It is still half of the button, so between the title and the image is one big gap.

Does anyone know if there is any way to resize the imageView?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957317/how-do-i-scale-a-uibuttons-imageview. You also could just use a UIImageView and register a UITapGestureRecognizer on it.

Comment: @dehlen Tried some of the solutions in that questions, unfortunaly haven't got the right one, but will try some more. 
Can't use UIImageView because I need to have text next to it.