# Proper Autoresizing mask configuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autoresizingmask

I am trying to duplicate this programmatically:

[image]

I have seen there is a lot of confusion with how Apple handles this. I tried the following, but it doesn't work for me:

```
[buttonTop setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Any ideas where to go from here?

**Update:**

The code for my button is as follows:

```
buttonTop = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
buttonTop.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
buttonTop.center = self.view.center;
buttonTop.layer.cornerRadius = buttonTop.frame.size.width / 2;
buttonTop.clipsToBounds = YES;
buttonTop.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[buttonTop setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

if (GetUserProPic){
    [buttonTop sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:GetUserProPic] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonTop sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:GetUserProPic] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
} else {
    [buttonTop setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonTop setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar_icon"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}

[self.view addSubview:buttonTop];
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

However, I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be using auto resizing masks any more except in legacy apps, and even there, you should really update them to Auto-Layout.

Comment: @DuncanC I disagree. There are various tools available. Use what works in a given situation. There is nothing wrong with autoresizing masks.

Comment: @jape You need to clarify what you mean by "doesn't work". And provide more details about how the button is created and setup. Put all of this info into your question, not in comments.

Comment: Try setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to No

Comment: @rmaddy I just updated my question. Thank you!

Comment: @SahanaKini Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: @jape Your "music" images seem to indicate an issue with the width but your code and setup is only dealing with the height.

Comment: "I am trying to duplicate this programmatically" Why?

Comment: @rmaddy I had the same issue with other images and that was a solution that worked for those, so I assumed it would work for this as well. If you have another suggestion, I'm open to it!

Comment: @matt The button is generated programmatically, so I cannot edit it with the Storyboard editor.

Comment: Fine. You can do anything in code that you can do with the storyboard editor. However, this does not explain why you want to use the `autoresizingMask` to configure this object.

Comment: @matt I don't know how else to prevent the distortion of the image. If you have any ideas, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: I don't have any "ideas" because you have not at all explained what's going on or what you're trying to do. You asked some irrelevant question about autoresizing, instead of asking about what you are _really_ trying to achieve. In your screen shot, what is the "MUSIC" word and what is the black circle? Are they two different objects? What? Try to provide some useful explanation of what you're trying to do (as you were asked to do several hours ago).

Comment: @matt I'm not sure what kind of other context you're looking for. The code clearly shows the "black circle" is a button with an image ("music word") on it. The image is not being scaled properly to fit in the button. Instead of implying I didn't ask a good question, maybe you could ask for clarification considering everyone else seemed to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The button's autoResizeMask affects the button's size when the view containing the button changes size.  It does not affect the content inside the button.  (And I think the default settings will shrink the image as needed, but not expand it.)

Try code from this SO answer: [How do I scale a UIButton's imageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957317/how-do-i-scale-a-uibuttons-imageview)

```
buttonTop.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
```