# The simplest way to resize an UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimage, resize

In my iPhone app, I take a picture with the camera, then I want to resize it to 290*390 pixels. I was using this method to resize the image :

```
UIImage *newImage = [image _imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(290, 390)
                         interpolationQuality:1];
```

It works perfectly, but it's an undocumented function, so I can't use it anymore with iPhone OS4.

So... what is the simplest way to resize an UIImage ?

Comment: The way to do it in 2019,  https://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

Answer (score 790, accepted):

The simplest way is to set the frame of your `UIImageView` and set the `contentMode` to one of the resizing options.

Or you can use this utility method, if you actually need to resize an image:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Example usage:

```
#import "MYUtil.h"
…
UIImage *myIcon = [MYUtil imageWithImage:myUIImageInstance scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
```

Comment: [As of iOS 4.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW29), the UIGraphics* functions are all thread-safe.

Comment: Just want to note here if you're using this in share extension (where memory is limitted ~100MB). You should use scale factor 0 in UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions. Otherwise, extension can be crash with some big image

Answer (score 127):

Proper **Swift 3.0** for **iOS 10+** solution: Using `ImageRenderer` and closure syntax:

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageWith(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize).image { _ in
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
        }
        
        return image.withRenderingMode(renderingMode)
    }
}
```

And here's the Objective-C version:

```
@implementation UIImage (ResizeCategory)
- (UIImage *)imageWithSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsImageRenderer *renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc] initWithSize:newSize];
    UIImage *image = [renderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext*_Nonnull myContext) {
        [self drawInRect:(CGRect) {.origin = CGPointZero, .size = newSize}];
    }];
    return [image imageWithRenderingMode:self.renderingMode];
}
@end
```

Comment: When copying the new image object to the clipboard it produces a white block for me. It's not actually resizing the image view?

Comment: this function returning an image of 0 height and 0 width, expect height is 9000 height and 9000 width.

Comment: Note that this doesn't resize the underlying CGImage (at least in iOS 12.1).  Which is okay based on the question, but if you are writing out the image, you'll have to use the cgImage, and you'll get the original image.

Comment: @prewett As of Xcode 13.2.1, `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` creates a new `CGImage` with a new size to reflect the new `UIImage`.

Answer (score 92):

Here's a Swift version of [Paul Lynch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658801/996404)

```
func imageWithImage(image:UIImage, scaledToSize newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

And as an extension:

```swift
public extension UIImage {
    func copy(newSize: CGSize, retina: Bool = true) -> UIImage? {
        // In next line, pass 0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
        // Pass 1 to force exact pixel size.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
            /* size: */ newSize,
            /* opaque: */ false,
            /* scale: */ retina ? 0 : 1
        )
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

Comment: just noted that, in iOS, your newSize will multiple by 2x, 3x based on device

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, image.scale); for all devices

Comment: Note that this doesn't resize the underlying CGImage (at least in iOS 12.1).  Which is okay based on the question, but if you are writing out the image, you'll have to use the cgImage, and you'll get the original image.

Answer (score 66):

A more compact version for Swift 4 and iOS 10+:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resized(to size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let resizedImage = image.resized(to: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
```

Answer (score 40):

## Swift solution for Stretch Fill, Aspect Fill and Aspect Fit

```
extension UIImage {
    enum ContentMode {
        case contentFill
        case contentAspectFill
        case contentAspectFit
    }
    
    func resize(withSize size: CGSize, contentMode: ContentMode = .contentAspectFill) -> UIImage? {
        let aspectWidth = size.width / self.size.width
        let aspectHeight = size.height / self.size.height
        
        switch contentMode {
        case .contentFill:
            return resize(withSize: size)
        case .contentAspectFit:
            let aspectRatio = min(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)
            return resize(withSize: CGSize(width: self.size.width * aspectRatio, height: self.size.height * aspectRatio))
        case .contentAspectFill:
            let aspectRatio = max(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)
            return resize(withSize: CGSize(width: self.size.width * aspectRatio, height: self.size.height * aspectRatio))
        }
    }
    
    private func resize(withSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, self.scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        draw(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

and to use you can do the following:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")!
let newImage = image.resize(withSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 150), contentMode: .contentAspectFill)
```

Thanks to abdullahselek for his original solution.

Answer (score 26):

I've also seen this done as well (which I use on `UIButtons` for Normal and Selected state since buttons don't `resize` to fit).  Credit goes to whoever the original author was.

First make an empty .h and .m file called `UIImageResizing.h` and `UIImageResizing.m`

```
// Put this in UIImageResizing.h
@interface UIImage (Resize)
- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size;
@end

// Put this in UIImageResizing.m
@implementation UIImage (Resize)

- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height), self.CGImage);

UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return scaledImage;
}

@end
```

Include that .h file in whatever .m file you're going to use the function in and then call it like this:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"largeImage.png"];
UIImage* smallImage = [image scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(100.0f,100.0f)];
```

Comment: This doesn't copy over image orientation.

Answer (score 20):

This improvement to Paul's code will give you a sharp high res image on an iPhone with a retina display. Otherwise when scaling down it's blurry.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, 2.0);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    }
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
}
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, the changes you have made are unnecessary, since supplying a value of 0.0 for the scale in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` will automatically use the main screen's scale (as of iOS 3.2).

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple way:

```
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
    CGSize sacleSize = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sacleSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sacleSize.width, sacleSize.height)];
    UIImage * resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**resizedImage** is a new image.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a modification of the category written by iWasRobbed above. It keeps the aspect ratio of the original image instead of distorting it.

```
- (UIImage*)scaleToSizeKeepAspect:(CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGFloat ws = size.width/self.size.width;
    CGFloat hs = size.height/self.size.height;

    if (ws > hs) {
        ws = hs/ws;
        hs = 1.0;
    } else {
        hs = ws/hs;
        ws = 1.0;
    }

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(size.width/2-(size.width*ws)/2,
        size.height/2-(size.height*hs)/2, size.width*ws,
        size.height*hs), self.CGImage);

    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

When using **iOS 15** or newer, you can use the new `prepareThumbnail` method of `UIImage`:

```
sourceImage.prepareThumbnail(of: thumbnailSize) { thumbnail in
    // Do something with the resized image
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.imageView?.image = thumbnail
    }
}
```

More info here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3750845-preparethumbnail

Comment: Do you know @Ely if that method takes the screen scale value into account ?

Comment: @BlazejSLEBODA No, it doesn't multiply the thumbnail size parameter value with `UIScreen.main.scale`, you have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 13):

Why so complicated? I think using system API can achieve the same result:

```
UIImage *largeImage;
CGFloat ratio = 0.4; // you want to get a new image that is 40% the size of large image.
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:largeImage.CGImage
                                        scale:1/ratio
                                  orientation:largeImage.imageOrientation];
// notice the second argument, it is 1/ratio, not ratio.
```

The only gotcha is you should pass inverse of target ratio as the second argument, as according to the document the second parameter specifies the ratio of original image compared to the new scaled one.

Comment: Because scale(%) is not the same thing as pixels(w/h).

Comment: The scale should be largeImage.scale/ratio not 1/ratio.

Answer (score 12):

For Swift 5:

```
extension UIImage {
  func resized(to newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

    draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this drain your memory unessecarily? I think it is better to use UIGraphicsImageRenderer. Source: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416/

Answer (score 11):

If you just want an image smaller and don't care about exact size:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, YES, scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Setting scale to `0.25f` will give you a 816 by 612 image from a 8MP camera.

Here's [a category UIImage+Scale](https://gist.github.com/sanmai/6593048) for those who needs one.

Answer (score 11):

This is an UIImage extension compatible with **Swift 3** and **Swift 4** which scales image to given size with an aspect ratio

```
extension UIImage {

    func scaledImage(withSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        draw(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    }

    func scaleImageToFitSize(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let aspect = self.size.width / self.size.height
        if size.width / aspect <= size.height {
            return scaledImage(withSize: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.width / aspect))
        } else {
            return scaledImage(withSize: CGSize(width: size.height * aspect, height: size.height))
        }
    }

}
```

Example usage

```
let image = UIImage(named: "apple")
let scaledImage = image.scaleImageToFitSize(size: CGSize(width: 45.0, height: 45.0))
```

Comment: I would recommend to name the function `scaledImage(with size:)` or `scaledWithSize(_:)`. Also  `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` cannot really return `nil`, therefore `!` would work as well. You can also simplify rect creation to `CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)`.

Answer (score 8):

I found a category for UIImage in Apple's own examples which does the same trick. Here's the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Listings/AirDropSample_UIImage_Resize_m.html.

You'll just have to change the call:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, 2.0);
```

in `imageWithImage:scaledToSize:inRect:` with:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 2.0);
```

In order to consider the alpha channel in the image.

Answer (score 8):

For my fellow Xamarians, here is a **Xamarin.iOS** C# version of @Paul Lynch answer.

```
private UIImage ResizeImage(UIImage image, CGSize newSize) 
{
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0f);
    image.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));
    UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage 
{
        let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
        let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight))
        image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to add some descriptive text to go with your code.

Answer (score 6):

**Effective approach without stretching image Swift 4**

```
// Method to resize image
func resize(image: UIImage, toScaleSize:CGSize) -> UIImage {
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(toScaleSize, true, image.scale)
                        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: toScaleSize.width, height: toScaleSize.height))
                        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                        return scaledImage!
                }
```

**// Call method**

```
    let resizedImage = self.resize(image: UIImage(named: "YourImageName")!, toScaleSize: CGSize(width: 290, height: 390))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make a thumbnail of a UIImage (with proportional resizing or maybe some cropping involved), check out [UIImage+Resize](https://github.com/mustangostang/UIImage-Resize) category that allows you to use concise, ImageMagick-like syntax:

```
UIImage* squareImage       = [image resizedImageByMagick: @"320x320#"];
```

Answer (score 5):

[Rogerio Chaves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24498221/160917) answer as a swift extension

```
func scaledTo(size: CGSize) -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0);
    self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

And also bonus

```
func scaledTo(height: CGFloat) -> UIImage{
    let width = height*self.size.width/self.size.height
    return scaledTo(size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[cf Chris] To resize *to* a desired size:

```
UIImage *after = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:before.CGImage
                                     scale:CGImageGetHeight(before.CGImage)/DESIREDHEIGHT
                               orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

or, equivalently, substitute `CGImageGetWidth(...)/DESIREDWIDTH`

Comment: Note that the image data itself is not resized but a scale factor is applied which means image is of the same size in memory.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3.0 with failsafe option (returns the original image in case of error):

```
func resize(image: UIImage, toSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,false,1.0)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    if let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return resizedImage
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 5):

(Swift 4 compatible) iOS 10+ and iOS < 10 solution (using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` if possible, `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` otherwise)

```
/// Resizes an image
///
/// - Parameter newSize: New size
/// - Returns: Resized image
func scaled(to newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)

    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize)
        return renderer.image { _ in
            self.draw(in: rect)
        }
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
        self.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use this extension

```
extension UIImage {
    public func resize(size:CGSize, completionHandler:(resizedImage:UIImage, data:NSData?)->()) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), { () -> Void in
            let newSize:CGSize = size
            let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
            self.drawInRect(rect)
            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.5)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                completionHandler(resizedImage: newImage, data:imageData)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Paul Lynch's answer is great, but it would change the image ratio. 
if you don`t want to change the image ratio, and still want the new image fit for new size, try this.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

// calculate a new size which ratio is same to original image
CGFloat ratioW = image.size.width / newSize.width;
CGFloat ratioH = image.size.height / newSize.height;

CGFloat ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height;

CGSize showSize = CGSizeZero;
if (ratioW > 1 && ratioH > 1) { 

    if (ratioW > ratioH) { 
        showSize.width = newSize.width;
        showSize.height = showSize.width / ratio;
    } else {
        showSize.height = newSize.height;
        showSize.width = showSize.height * ratio;
    }

} else if (ratioW > 1) {

    showSize.width = showSize.width;
    showSize.height = showSize.width / ratio;

} else if (ratioH > 1) {

    showSize.height = showSize.height;
    showSize.width = showSize.height * ratio;

}

//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
// In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
// Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(showSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, showSize.width, showSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way of resizing an UIImage:

```swift
// Resize to height = 100 points.
let originalImage = UIImage(named: "MyOriginalImage")!
let resizingFactor = 100 / originalImage.size.height
let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: originalImage.cgImage!, scale: originalImage.scale / resizingFactor, orientation: .up)
```

Answer (score 3):

Some time your image have `scale` large than `1` so that resize image will make an image unexpected. This is my solution for this case.

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeTo(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        // Important thing here
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = 1
        
        let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize, format: format).image { _ in
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
        }
            
        return image.withRenderingMode(renderingMode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here my somewhat-verbose Swift code

```
func scaleImage(image:UIImage,  toSize:CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(toSize, false, 0.0);

    let aspectRatioAwareSize = self.aspectRatioAwareSize(image.size, boxSize: toSize, useLetterBox: false)


    let leftMargin = (toSize.width - aspectRatioAwareSize.width) * 0.5
    let topMargin = (toSize.height - aspectRatioAwareSize.height) * 0.5


    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(leftMargin, topMargin, aspectRatioAwareSize.width , aspectRatioAwareSize.height))
    let retVal = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return retVal
}

func aspectRatioAwareSize(imageSize: CGSize, boxSize: CGSize, useLetterBox: Bool) -> CGSize {
    // aspect ratio aware size
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/6565988/8047
    let imageWidth = imageSize.width
    let imageHeight = imageSize.height
    let containerWidth = boxSize.width
    let containerHeight = boxSize.height

    let imageAspectRatio = imageWidth/imageHeight
    let containerAspectRatio = containerWidth/containerHeight

    let retVal : CGSize
    // use the else at your own risk: it seems to work, but I don't know 
    // the math
    if (useLetterBox) {
        retVal = containerAspectRatio > imageAspectRatio ? CGSizeMake(imageWidth * containerHeight / imageHeight, containerHeight) : CGSizeMake(containerWidth, imageHeight * containerWidth / imageWidth)
    } else {
        retVal = containerAspectRatio < imageAspectRatio ? CGSizeMake(imageWidth * containerHeight / imageHeight, containerHeight) : CGSizeMake(containerWidth, imageHeight * containerWidth / imageWidth)
    }

    return retVal
}
```

Comment: Please note: You might want to add a precondition (`guard`) to the `aspectRatioAwareSize` function such that it won't throw a divide by zero exception if the input parameters for either imageSize or boxSize are `CGSize.zero`

Comment: @pkluz this is a good suggestion, but you'd need them all over the function, I think, since each variable is the divisor of another line... I'm going to leave this as is for clarity. For production or a library for github, you might want to beef this up... More than a guard, I'm concerned that the function uses short variable names that don't say much. I'd probably fix that first, and then add guards for other things, and then add unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 2.0 :**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
let newSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
let imageResized = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 answer:

```
func scaleDown(image: UIImage, withSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(withSize, false, scale)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: withSize.width, height: withSize.height))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

Comment: No need to set the real scale: `The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.`

Answer (score 2):

Use this extension, in case you need to resize width/height only with aspect ratio.

```
extension UIImage {
    func resize(to size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
    func resize(width: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        return resize(to: CGSize(width: width, height: width / (size.width / size.height)))
    }
    func resize(height: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        return resize(to: CGSize(width: height * (size.width / size.height), height: height))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that it's difficult to find an answer that you can use out-of-the box in your **Swift 3** project. The main problem of other answers that they don't honor the alpha-channel of the image. Here is the technique that I'm using in my projects.

```
extension UIImage {

    func scaledToFit(toSize newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        if (size.width < newSize.width && size.height < newSize.height) {
            return copy() as! UIImage
        }

        let widthScale = newSize.width / size.width
        let heightScale = newSize.height / size.height

        let scaleFactor = widthScale < heightScale ? widthScale : heightScale
        let scaledSize = CGSize(width: size.width * scaleFactor, height: size.height * scaleFactor)

        return self.scaled(toSize: scaledSize, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: scaledSize.width, height: scaledSize.height))
    }

    func scaled(toSize newSize: CGSize, in rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        if UIScreen.main.scale == 2.0 {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, !hasAlphaChannel, 2.0)
        }
        else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
        }

        draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage ?? UIImage()
    }

    var hasAlphaChannel: Bool {
        guard let alpha = cgImage?.alphaInfo else {
            return false
        }
        return alpha == CGImageAlphaInfo.first ||
            alpha == CGImageAlphaInfo.last ||
            alpha == CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst ||
            alpha == CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let size = CGSize(width: 14.0, height: 14.0)
    if let image = UIImage(named: "barbell")?.scaledToFit(toSize: size) {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

This code is a rewrite of [Apple's extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/sc2273/Listings/AirDropSample_UIImage_Resize_m.html) with added support for images with and without alpha channel.

As a further reading I recommend checking [this article](http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/) for different image resizing techniques. Current approach offers decent performance, it operates high-level APIs and easy to understand. I recommend sticking to it unless you find that image resizing is a bottleneck in your performance.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5:

```
func imageWithImage(_ image: UIImage?, scaledToSize newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
    image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
    let newImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Usage:

```
let img: UIImage? = imageWithImage(UIImage(named: "DefaultAvatar"), scaledToSize:CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
```