# High Quality Scaling of UIImage

Tags: ios, image, uikit, uiimage

I need to scale the resolution of an image coming from a view layer in an iPhone application.  The obvious way is to specify a scale factor in UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions, but any time the scale factor is not 1.0 then quality of the image goes to pot -- far more than would be expected from the loss of pixels.

I've tried several other scaling techniques, but they all seem to revolve around CGContext stuff and all appear to do the same thing.

Simply changing image "size" (without changing the dot resolution) isn't sufficient, mostly because that info seems to be discarded very quickly by other hands in the pipeline (the image will be converted to a JPG and emailed).

Is there any other way to scale an image on iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About **UIImage** resize problem, [this post](https://github.com/mbcharbonneau/UIImage-Categories/blob/master/UIImage%2BResize.m) give many ways to handle UIImage object. The **UIImage** has some orientation problems need to be fixed. [This](https://github.com/mbcharbonneau/UIImage-Categories/blob/master/UIImage%2BResize.m) and [Another post](https://github.com/AliSoftware/UIImage-Resize/blob/master/UIImage%2BResize.m) will address it.

---

```
-(UIImage*)resizedImageToSize:(CGSize)dstSize
{
    CGImageRef imgRef = self.CGImage;
    // the below values are regardless of orientation : for UIImages from Camera, width>height (landscape)
    CGSize  srcSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef)); // not equivalent to self.size (which is dependant on the imageOrientation)!

    /* Don't resize if we already meet the required destination size. */
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(srcSize, dstSize)) {
        return self;
    }

    CGFloat scaleRatio = dstSize.width / srcSize.width;

    // Handle orientation problem of UIImage
    UIImageOrientation orient = self.imageOrientation;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    switch(orient) {

        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.width, srcSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, srcSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.height, srcSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI_2);
            break;  

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6  
            dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, srcSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI_2);
            break;  

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7  
            dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;  

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8  
            dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;  

        default:  
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];  

    }  

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // The actual resize: draw the image on a new context, applying a transform matrix
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(dstSize, NO, self.scale);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

       if (!context) {
           return nil;
       }

    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -srcSize.height, 0);
    } else {  
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -srcSize.height);
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    // we use srcSize (and not dstSize) as the size to specify is in user space (and we use the CTM to apply a scaleRatio)
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, srcSize.width, srcSize.height), imgRef);
    UIImage* resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resizedImage;
}
```

Comment: It gave me some ideas.  I'm going to have a shot at doing a 50% scaling by taking every other pixel of every other row.

Comment: ... and this is why link-only answers are useless.

Answer (score 6):

Swift extension:

```
extension UIImage{

        // returns a scaled version of the image
        func imageScaledToSize(size : CGSize, isOpaque : Bool) -> UIImage{

            // begin a context of the desired size
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, isOpaque, 0.0)

            // draw image in the rect with zero origin and size of the context
            let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size)
            self.drawInRect(imageRect)

            // get the scaled image, close the context and return the image
            let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return scaledImage
       }
}
```

Example:

```
aUIImageView.image = aUIImage.imageScaledToSize(aUIImageView.bounds.size, isOpaque : false)
```

Set isOpaque to true if the image has no alpha: drawing will have better performance.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this algorithm to create a half-size image:

```
- (UIImage*) halveImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage {

    // Compute the target size
    CGSize sourceSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGSize targetSize;
    targetSize.width = (int) (sourceSize.width / 2);
    targetSize.height = (int) (sourceSize.height / 2);

    // Access the source data bytes
    NSData* sourceData = (NSData*) CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(sourceImage.CGImage));
    unsigned char* sourceBytes = (unsigned char *)[sourceData bytes];

    // Some info we'll need later
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(sourceImage.CGImage);
    int bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(sourceImage.CGImage);
    int bitsPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(sourceImage.CGImage);
    int __attribute__((unused)) bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / 8;
    int sourceBytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(sourceImage.CGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(sourceImage.CGImage);

    assert(bytesPerPixel == 4);
    assert(bitsPerComponent == 8);

    // Bytes per row is (apparently) rounded to some boundary
    assert(sourceBytesPerRow >= ((int) sourceSize.width) * 4);
    assert([sourceData length] == ((int) sourceSize.height) * sourceBytesPerRow);

    // Allocate target data bytes
    int targetBytesPerRow = ((int) targetSize.width) * 4;
    // Algorigthm happier if bytes/row a multiple of 16
    targetBytesPerRow = (targetBytesPerRow + 15) & 0xFFFFFFF0;
    int targetBytesSize = ((int) targetSize.height) * targetBytesPerRow;
    unsigned char* targetBytes = (unsigned char*) malloc(targetBytesSize);
    UIImage* targetImage = nil;

    // Copy source to target, averaging 4 pixels into 1
    for (int row = 0; row < targetSize.height; row++) {
        unsigned char* sourceRowStart = sourceBytes + (2 * row * sourceBytesPerRow);
        unsigned char* targetRowStart = targetBytes + (row * targetBytesPerRow);
        for (int column = 0; column < targetSize.width; column++) {

            int sourceColumnOffset = 2 * column * 4;
            int targetColumnOffset = column * 4;

            unsigned char* sourcePixel = sourceRowStart + sourceColumnOffset;
            unsigned char* nextRowSourcePixel = sourcePixel + sourceBytesPerRow;
            unsigned char* targetPixel = targetRowStart + targetColumnOffset;

            uint32_t* sourceWord = (uint32_t*) sourcePixel;
            uint32_t* nextRowSourceWord = (uint32_t*) nextRowSourcePixel;
            uint32_t* targetWord = (uint32_t*) targetPixel;

            uint32_t sourceWord0 = sourceWord[0];
            uint32_t sourceWord1 = sourceWord[1];
            uint32_t sourceWord2 = nextRowSourceWord[0];
            uint32_t sourceWord3 = nextRowSourceWord[1];

            // This apparently bizarre sequence scales the data bytes by 4 so that when added together we'll get an average.  We do lose the least significant bits this way, and thus about half a bit of resolution.
            sourceWord0 = (sourceWord0 & 0xFCFCFCFC) >> 2;
            sourceWord1 = (sourceWord1 & 0xFCFCFCFC) >> 2;
            sourceWord2 = (sourceWord2 & 0xFCFCFCFC) >> 2;
            sourceWord3 = (sourceWord3 & 0xFCFCFCFC) >> 2;

            uint32_t resultWord = sourceWord0 + sourceWord1 + sourceWord2 + sourceWord3;
            targetWord[0] = resultWord;
        }
    }

    // Convert the bits to an image.  Supposedly CGCreateImage will dispose of the target bytes buffer.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, targetBytes, targetBytesSize, NULL);
    CGImageRef targetRef = CGImageCreate(targetSize.width, targetSize.height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, targetBytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, FALSE, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    targetImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:targetRef];

    // Clean up
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Return result
    return targetImage;
}
```

I tried just taking every other pixel of every other row, instead of averaging, but it resulted in an image about as bad as the default algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use something like [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). Apparently it's been successfully ported to iPhone: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=14089

I've always been satisfied with the quality of images scaled by this library, so I think you'll be satisfied with the result.

Comment: links are not working could u please share code for resizing UIImage without loosing resolution