# convert 16 bit Infrared data to meaningful data in C/Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, pointers

I have an API that returns the 16-bit Infrared data from a file.
The usage is like this:

`UInt16 *irDataResult = IrbGetIrData16([self.path UTF8String]);`

The length of the the data pointed by the pointer is : 1024x768x2.

I want to convert it in to an int 2 dimensional array so that I have individual pixels and then I can use one of the UIImage functions to create image out of my raw data.
The I way I'm doing is this:

```
 int dataArray[width][height];
    int *dataPointer = &dataArray[0][0];
    int byteNum = 0;

    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            dataArray[w][h] = irDataSource[byteNum] <<0 | irDataSource[byteNum] << 8; //Little endian
            byteNum++;
        }
    }
```

The loop runs fine, but after a little while it gives my BAD_ACCESS error.
What am I doing wrong?
Also, is this the right approach?

Comment: How is declared `irDataSource`?

Comment: why is dataPointer declared int* and not UInt16* ?

Comment: `int dataArray[width][height];`  Are `width` and `height` constant/literal values?  What are the values?

Comment: You need to be aware that `int` does not have a defined width, but varies with the version of Xcode.  And at some point you will need to convert this data into something that a UIImage can accept -- either a PNG or a JPEG.  It may be better to work directly with graphics buffers, since you can feed in a pixel map directly.  (But I can't offhand give you a reference for that.)

Comment: (And I believe there's a defined "swap bytes" function somewhere, though I can't say where.)

Comment: It's a lot to digest, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052188/high-quality-scaling-of-uiimage) involves manipulating graphics data using techniques you may find useful.

Comment: Irdatasource is uint16*. I tried with uint16 as well and I got the bad access error..width and height are 1024 and 768.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is due to accessing `dataArray` and not `irDataSource`?  (Hint: Break the failing line in half -- access the source value on one line and set the target on the next.  Then you will be able to tell which part is failing.)

Comment: Sorry, but if you don't know whether `irDataSource` should be `uint16*` or `uint16` then you don't understand C pointers well enough to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Hotlicks: thanks for the vote of confidence. Here is the API signature.    unsigned short *IrbGetIrData16( const char *pFilename );

Comment: So, what does the documentation say about the "lifetime" of the returned pointer?

Comment: @hotlicks: Thanks for asking the question. the pointer stays "alive" till it is freed. So user has total control over it.

Comment: thanks you all  for the help. @Hotlicks: Your link on graphics definitely helped.