# How can I resize my UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

Here is the code I am using to resize my UIImage, but unfortunately it isn't working:

```
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"warning.png"];

CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 12.0);
CGImageRef croppedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([cellImage CGImage], cropRect);

UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cropRect];
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImage]]; 

CGImageRelease(croppedImage);
```

Why does this code not work?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is it doing/not doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize the image programatically in objective-c in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712329/how-to-resize-the-image-programatically-in-objective-c-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you forgetting to add `myImageView` as a subview of your main view or another visible view?  E.g.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
```

This would explain why nothing appears.

However, `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()` crops the image within the rect if your rect is smaller than the image.  To resize the UIImage itself, see: [The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

However, it's easiest if you just let the UIImageView handle the resizing if you don't actually need the UIImage itself resized.

```
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"warning.png"];
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 12.0);
CGImageRef croppedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([cellImage CGImage], CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,cellImage.size.width,cellImage.size.height));
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cropRect];
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImage]]; 
CGImageRelease(croppedImage);
[cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
```

See:

- [UITableViewCell Class Reference: **contentView**](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW18)

Comment: works, but the image is in the very left hand corner of the screen, this is the image in my UITableView cell. How can I get it to align in the cell?

Comment: instead of adding as a subview to the UIViewController's view, add it as a subview to your `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView` property.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

HI try this:-

```
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(50,50));
       [[UIImage imageNamed:@"warning.png"] drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0,50,50)];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that doesn't work but try using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext and UIGraphicsEndImageContext instead, UIGraphicsBeginImageContext takes a size.