# How do I prevent images from being stretched in scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage

`AspectFill` doesn't work so well with `ScrollView`.

This is my code

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageCount= page;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageCount, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [imageView setImageWithURL:[self.urlArray objectAtIndex:self.pageCount] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRedraw];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

}
```

Comment: Can your explain your problem and give some more details?

Comment: You can draw the image on the view and add the view as sub view of scrollview

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
[scrollView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[imageView sizeToFit];
```

Should work :-)

Comment: Made some images really small and in some cases one could see multiples of the same image on the scrollview

Comment: your images may be of different sizes! maintain a common size ratio for all the entries in scrollview

Comment: I'm getting the photos from flickr so I need to somehow resize them without stretching them.

Comment: Resizing is quite simple, you can use a common method and pass each of your image before adding to the scrollviewarray, see this [method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4712537/1756131)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your scroll view has `autoresizesSubviews` enabled, disable it and your images will appear (and the default view mode for images should be just fine)

Answer (score 0):

Set `scrollview` `contentmode` `aspectfill`.