# iOS App is crashing when display large size image from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage, xcode7.3, ios9.3

I have tried following libraries for Image cache:

- **SDWebImage**
- **UIImageView+AFNetworking**

But still app getting **Memory Warning, crashed and stuck** while scrolling.

I have used `UITableViewCell` for display image.

Some of the **images are 1.5 MB or more**, So i am not sure whether this is the issue or anything else?

Please guide.
Any efforts from your side will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have `UITableViewCell` for load `UICollectionViewCell` in `UITableView`:

**Code for UITableViewCell.**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"homecell";

    HomeViewCell *cell = (HomeViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSArray *arr=[[arrPsots objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] valueForKey:@"PostImage"];
    [cell setCollectionWithImageArray:arr];

    return cell;
}
```

**Code for UICollectionViewCell.**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ScrollCollectionCell";
    ScrollCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView1 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *imgKey = (IS_IPAD?@"PostImage":@"PostImage");
    NSString *strImage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrImages valueForKey:imgKey]];

    [cell.imgScroll setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    if ([arrImages count]==1) {

        self.pageControllPostImg.hidden=TRUE;
    }
    self.pageControllPostImg.hidden=TRUE;
    self.pageControllPostImg.numberOfPages=[arrImages count];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: could u pls show code related to retrieving and showing image ?

Comment: As @TejaNandamuri said, we need to see some code. In the meantime, you might want to check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177205/handling-download-of-very-large-images-with-sdwebimage) question of mine, and a related issue [HERE](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/pull/769) in the `SDWebImage` library itself.

Comment: Do you use reusable cells?

Comment: Hi guys.. I have added code. Please check and let us know if any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in one project, where previous programmer create new cell every time and didn't use reusable cells.

Comment: I have added code after "EDIT" please see the code.

Comment: try replace     HomeViewCell *cell = (HomeViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
with     HomeViewCell *cell = (HomeViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: i will appreciate your help in this regard. But still no improvement in any issue which is mentioned in question.

Comment: Its random and comes from API.

Comment: are u still have a problem?

Comment: Yes, but i think issue is due to image.

Comment: Try to reduce size of images. Better way, of course, when server does it.

Comment: Thanks Igor for your reply :)