# How to remove a header from a file that is .bmp using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, bmp

How to remove a header from a file that is .bmp using objective c.
I am getting 54 bytes extra. But in order to view image have to remove these 54 bytes and get actual image bytes.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:snapshotFile options:0 error:&error];
NSBitmapImageRep *imagerep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:data];
NSData *bytes = [imagerep representationUsingType:NSBMPFileType properties:nil];
```

My image is of width = 1280 and height = 800, so total image bytes should be 800*1280*5= 4096000.

But when i checked for bytes calculated above it was 4096054 bytes.
It seems that 54 extra is header.
I want to remove these header bytes in order to get actual image.

Any help will be really appreciated.
And please excuse in case this has already been answered.

Comment: Please excuse if its a basic question or discussed across different forums. I am new to the imaging part and did lot of googling, but not able to get the perfect understanding.

Comment: I expect that you will get more answers if you post the code you have so far.

Comment: Added code snippet. @EricHauenstein thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

BMP is the native bitmap format of Windows and is used to store virtually any type of bitmap data. For Cocoa/Cocoa-touch, we typically use PNG. As for reducing the size of an image programmatically in Objective-C, please:

[Refer to this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712329/how-to-resize-the-image-programatically-in-objective-c-in-iphone)

Comment: I am using the image for displaying it in case of remote management. That is why I require uncompressed image.