# ffmpeg resize down larger video to fit desired size and add padding

Tags: ffmpeg, padding

I'm trying to resize a larger video to fit an area that I have. In order to achieve this I calculate first the dimensions of the resized video so That it fits my area, and then I try to add padding to this video so that the final result will have the desired dimension, keeping the aspect ratio as well.

So let's say that I have the original video dimensions of 1280x720 and to fit my area of 405x320 I need first to resize the video to 405x227. I do that. Everything is fine at this point. I do some math and I find out that I have to add 46 pixels of padding at the top and the bottom.

So the padding parameter of the command for that would be `-vf "pad=405:320:0:46:black"`. But each time I run the command I get an error like `Input area 0:46:405:273 not within the padded area 0:0:404:226`.

The only docs for padding that I found is this http://ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html#pad.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone had this problem before? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 45):

try `-vf "scale=iw*min(405/iw\,320/ih):ih*min(405/iw\,320/ih),pad=405:320:(405-iw)/2:(320-ih)/2"`

Edit to clarify what's going on in that line: you are asking how to scale one box to fit inside another box. The boxes might have different aspect ratios. If they do, you want to fill one dimension, and center along the other dimension.

```
# you defined the max width and max height in your original question
max_width     = 405
max_height    = 320

# first, scale the image to fit along one dimension
scale         = min(max_width/input_width, max_height/input_height)
scaled_width  = input_width  * scale
scaled_height = input_height * scale

# then, position the image on the padded background
padding_ofs_x = (max_width  - input_width) / 2
padding_ofs_y = (max_height - input_height) / 2
```

Answer (score 16):

Here is a generic filter expression for scaling (maintaining aspect ratio) and padding any source size to any target size:

```
-vf "scale=min(iw*TARGET_HEIGHT/ih\,TARGET_WIDTH):min(TARGET_HEIGHT\,ih*TARGET_WIDTH/iw),
     pad=TARGET_WIDTH:TARGET_HEIGHT:(TARGET_WIDTH-iw)/2:(TARGET_HEIGHT-ih)/2"
```

Replace `TARGET_WIDTH` and `TARGET_HEIGHT` with your desired values. I use this to pull a 200x120 padded thumbnail from any video. Props to [davin for his nice overview of the math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565703/math-algorithm-fit-image-to-screen-retain-aspect-ratio).

Comment: Best answer for me, easily scriptable.

Comment: This will work with anamorphic videos:
`-vf "scale=(iw*sar)*min(TARGET_WIDTH/(iw*sar)\,TARGET_HEIGHT/ih):ih*min(TARGET_WIDTH/(iw*sar)\,TARGET_HEIGHT/ih),
     pad=TARGET_WIDTH:TARGET_HEIGHT:(TARGET_WIDTH-iw)/2:(TARGET_HEIGHT-ih)/2"`

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
-vf 'scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:x=(640-iw)/2:y=(480-ih)/2:color=black'
```

According to FFmpeg documentation, the `force_original_aspect_ratio` option is useful to keep the original aspect ratio when scaling:

```
   force_original_aspect_ratio
       Enable decreasing or increasing output video width or height if
       necessary to keep the original aspect ratio. Possible values:

       disable
           Scale the video as specified and disable this feature.

       decrease
           The output video dimensions will automatically be decreased if
           needed.

       increase
           The output video dimensions will automatically be increased if
           needed.
```