# ffmpeg - scale not working on all my cases

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` to scale and change speed of my videos.

And below script was not worked:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.666*PTS[i]; [i]scale=640:640[j]; [0:a]atempo=1.5[p]" -map "[j]" -map "[p]" output.mp4 2>&1
```

More simple script I testes also not working

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "scale=640:640" output.mp4 2>&1
```

Original video have resolution `1280x720`, and I want to resize to `640x640`, with padding `320` left and right.

What are my wrongs in script?
Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Could you please specify what do you mean under "not working"? Do you get any errors, or the result file doesn't look like you inteded?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have problem with the scaling part, so try this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "setpts=0.666,scale=w=min(iw*640/ih\,640):h=min(640\,ih*640/iw),pad=w=640:h=640:x=(640-iw)/2:y=(640-ih)/2; atempo=1.5" output.mp4
```

Here's the scaling filter:

```
scale=w=min(iw*HEIGHT/ih\,WIDTH):h=min(HEIGHT\,ih*WIDTH/iw),pad=w=WIDTH:h=HEIGHT:x=(WIDTH-iw)/2:y=(HEIGHT-ih)/2
```

Source:
[ffmpeg resize down larger video to fit desired size and add padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133242/ffmpeg-resize-down-larger-video-to-fit-desired-size-and-add-padding)