# HTML5 Canvas Drag, Drop, and Resize Images

Tags: html, image-resizing, kineticjs

I am using this example in my site, http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/ , for resizing images.
but problem is that the image is not resizing proportionally.

eg-
width=200;
height=138;
when i am resigning width to 202 then height will change proportionally 
but it is not working for proportional change

Thanks sir

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893966/constrained-proportional-scaling-in-kineticjs

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here. It depends on version of the the browser. Area of canvas should always greater than image size so that you will stretch the image inside the canvas otherwise it will be disappeared. Also it depends where you are changing the values inside functions.