# iOS: Thumbnail of taken picture

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to develop a screen like Status Update of facebook, when the user takes a picture, I want create a thumbnail and add to a component (I think UICollectionView). What is the best way to do this? I can't find anything on internet. Is the CollectionView the best component to handle this?
I'm already take a picture and thumbnail, but how to add to this component dynamically?

[image: Status]

Answer (score 0):

The camera button should open an [image picker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to invite the user to take a picture.  The picker will invoke a [delegate method (didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069) that tells you it finished.  The picked image is in the info dictionary (see the info dictionary keys at the bottom of the delegate reference).  The VC can then extract the image from the result and [scale it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756665/how-to-adjust-a-image-size-after-using-uiimagepickercontroller-take-a-photo).

Comment: Ok, but how to add to a component to show to user? Like a Collection