# Resize the UIimage from iphone camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimage, image-resizing

i have this question:
I take a UIImage from the camera of the iphone. I would like to reduce this UIImage both as size (width and heigth), but also as size (bytes).
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched?

Check Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=resize+uiimage

Check Google: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Also:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7307-resizing-photo-new-uiimage.html
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5204-resize-image-high-quality.html

Comment: @GgSalent: well, 'the best' is always debateble because of different purposses: quality loss (blur, colors...), speed, final size. There's rearly one the BEST way.