# How to compress an image in iOS with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, zip, compression

I want to compress an image (jpeg and png).
I found this answer: 
[how to compress image in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769968/how-to-compress-image-in-iphone)

But this resizes the image or take down the quality (or both).
I want something like the program 7-zip does for pc.
It takes an image and compresses it and gives it .zip as extension.
The primary goal is to take down the amount of space it uses on the disk. 
It is possible to compress an image with objective-c in iOS?

Comment: Zipping or otherwise comprissing JPEG or PNG images is not going to save you much space, these are already quite efficient formats to store images. JPEG gives you a configurable and fair compression/quality tradeoff. Why not expiriment with that first, as in the answer you found already?

Comment: Note that neither JPEG and PNG images compress very well with a lossless algorithm like Zip. The gain for JPEG will probably be nil, as it already has a lossy compression (that you can fine-tune by recompressing at a lower quality). I'm guessing the gain for PNG will be negligible.

Comment: @ecotax: Hivemind! ;)