# iOS UIView Background Image

Tags: ios, uiview

I want to have a `UIImage`as a background image on a `UIView.`

Here is my code:

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login.png"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = background;
[background release];
```

The Problem is, that the scale is not okay. It scaled 640 to 480, so I can't tell it 100% sure but it looks like only 300 to 250 is displayed or something like that.

Is there a fit to scale / fit to UIView / fit to size modus?

Comment: What is the size of the original PNG?  Also are you viewing this on a retina device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the `UIColor` API:

> You can use pattern colors to set the fill or stroke color just as you would a solid color. During drawing, the image in the pattern color is tiled as necessary to cover the given area.

That means it tries to create a pattern out of your image to fill the area. I think the optimal way to do it is so rescale your image to fit exactly the `UIView` size.

There is a nice answer here how to resize your image during runtime:

[The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

Answer (score 54):

you are required to process your image before you add it,  try this :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

Comment: In case you got the image flipped, you have to change the context orientation with CGContextTranslateCTM()

Answer (score 29):

hello try this,

```
     self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login.png"]];
```

Comment: best answer, clear and works instantly. Perfect for a fast research.

Answer (score 13):

Specify an actual background and send it to the back of your view

```
//add background
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
[myView addSubview:background];
[myView sendSubviewToBack:background];
myView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 10):

In **Swift** use this...

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    UIImage(named: "1.png")?.drawInRect(self.view.bounds)

    var image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

Answer (score 9):

And if you want to do it in swift:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"background.jpg"))
```

Comment: and yes, I want to do it in Swift :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following extension in Swift:

```
extension UIView{

    func setBackgroundImage(img: UIImage){

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
        img.drawInRect(self.bounds)
        let patternImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: patternImage)
    }
}
```

In code you can use like this:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "HomeBg"){
        self.view.setBackgroundImage(image)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Interface Builder, add an `Image View` to `View` and select the image you want to use in `Attributes inspector`. Finally, make the `Image View` the very first child of the `View` by dragging the element in `Document Outline`.

Answer (score 1):

If the view is going to have the same size, you can place a method in your `AppDelegate.m` that scales the background image on first run, and then keeps the scaled image in memory for future use:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = nil;
- (void)setBackground:(UIView *)view
{
    if (backgroundImage == nil)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"] drawInRect:view.bounds];
        backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
}
```

Thanks to @uneakharsh for his help!

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to do this and I found that, due to *autolayout*, the `UIImageView` stretches the containing `UIView`, when I want it the other way: I want the `UIImageView` to take the size of the `UIView`.

So I created this class. It updates the `UIImageView` frame according to the `UIView` container whenever it is laid out via `layoutSubviews`.

```
/**
 * View with an image whose frame is adjusted to the frame of the view. 
 */
class ViewWithImage: UIView {

    let image: UIImageView

    init(image: UIImageView) {
        self.image = image
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.addSubview(image)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateImageFrame()
    }

    private func updateImageFrame() {
        image.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.frame.size)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("no init(coder:)") }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = background;
[background release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext** method to set the size of image same that of view.

Syntax :  **void     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize size);**

```
  #define IMAGE(imageName) (UIImage *)[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:IMAGE_TYPE_PNG]]

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@“MyImage.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:IMAGE(@"mainBg")];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage (UIImage.FromFile ("body_background.png"));
```