# How to change size of thumb image of UISlider programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uislider

I would like to make the custom UISlider,
something like this

|o----------| -> |-----O------|   -> |------------〇|

the `thumbImage` will be small at the minimum value, it will increase the size during the slider value increase, otherwise it will decrease.

is anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage).

The extra work you will have, will be a **method A** that will call the `imageWithImage:scaledToSize:` when the `UISlider's` value changes.

Comment: thx for Reply , i have added with the follow, am i right? But i test with trouble image size occur...                                                  
  float ratio = penSize_sld.value/( penSize_sld.maximumValue/2);
    CGSize ss= CGSizeMake(penSize_sld.currentThumbImage.size.width*ratio, penSize_sld.currentThumbImage.size.height*ratio);
    UIImage *changeImage = [UIImage imageWithImage:penSize_sld.currentThumbImage scaledToSize:ss];
    [penSize_sld setThumbImage:changeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if (sender == penSize_sld) {
        brushWidth = penSize_sld.value;
    }

Comment: That work! Thanks JackyBoy

   `float ratio = penSize_sld.value/( penSize_sld.maximumValue/2);
    
    if ( ratio < 0.8) {
        ratio = 0.8;
    }
    
    UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drawview_dragbar_bu_1.png" ofType:nil]];
    
    CGSize ss= CGSizeMake(thumbImage.size.width*ratio,thumbImage.size.height*ratio);
    UIImage *changeImage = [UIImage imageWithImage:thumbImage scaledToSize:ss];
    [penSize_sld setThumbImage:changeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   .....
    
}`

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3:

```
extension UIImage {

    func scaleToSize(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
        draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage
    }
}
```