# Custom UISlider without image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uislider

I'm trying to resize `UISlider` thumb in iOS7 but I can't. I know that can use `setThumbImage` but I don't want use any images.

```
setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderThumb.png"]
```

I want to change size and color of `UISlider` thumb without image. can I do this?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983726/uislider-thumbtintcolor-doesnt-change-on-ios-7-fine-on-ios-6, it can help you ;)

Comment: Color changed successfully, now my only question is: how to resize thumb? :)

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221966/how-to-change-size-of-thumb-image-of-uislider-programmatically, if you can't resize without using a thumb image, you can use a transparant image, then you can resize the thumb and change the color like you want.

Answer (score 2):

The SWIFT code below enables you to easily change the size and color of a slider thumb:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.updateSlider(self.mySlider, thumbSize: 16, color: UIColor.redColor())
}

func updateSlider(slider: UISlider, thumbSize: CGFloat, color: UIColor){
    let thumbImage = createThumbImage(thumbSize, color: color)
    slider.setThumbImage(thumbImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    slider.setThumbImage(thumbImage, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
}

func createThumbImage(size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let layerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(layerFrame.insetBy(dx: 1, dy: 1), nil)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = color.CGColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.65).CGColor

    let layer = CALayer.init()
    layer.frame = layerFrame
    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    return self.imageFromLayer(layer)
}

func imageFromLayer(layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return outputImage
}
```