# SDWebImage process images before caching

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, sdwebimage

I fetch a lot of images from the web, and they are all kind of sizes - they can be big, small etc..

So I can resize them when I display them in the cell but this is inefficient. It's way better to resize them after SDWebImage have download them and cache them resized, instead of storing large images on disk and resize them for every cell.

So how can I do this with SDWebImage, or I have to hack a bit onto the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, and tried tweaking SDWebImage first, but ended up building my own component that solved the problem. You can take take a look at it here : https://github.com/adig/RemoteImageView

Comment: This is great! Good job on the library. There are some annoyances, like the images reloading on every reloadData message, or images reappearing on every table scroll. You may take a look at this. Thanks and congrats!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If you're referring to the animation sequence on image load you can disable that using the animate property.

Comment: Hey, I submitted an issue regarding some bugs in your lib on github. You may want to take a look at it. :)

Answer (score 26):

SDWebImage developer Olivier Poitrey answered this question for me [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/330#issuecomment-14854936).

You have to implement the SDWebImageManagerDelegate protocol and then set it as the shared manager's delegate like this:

```
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.delegate = self;

using the imageManager:transformDownloadedImage:withURL: instance method.
```

[More information.](http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Protocols/SDWebImageManagerDelegate.html#//api/name/imageManager%3atransformDownloadedImage%3awithURL%3a)

Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: Sorry didn't get. I am using UIImageView+WebCache.h class's sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder method for each cell's image. What should I do, can you please tell in layman's terms.

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage 3.8.2

If using UIImageView category `sd_setImageWithURL`. I have created another UIImageView category (extension)

```
func modifiedImageFromUrl(url: NSURL?) {
    self.sd_setImageWithURL(url) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
        if cacheType == SDImageCacheType.None && image != nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
                let modifiedImage = // modify image as you want

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().saveImageToCache(modifiedImage, forURL: url)

                    self.image = modifiedImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice and all, but perhaps you should have specified where it was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Expansion on MaeSTRo's answer in **Swift 3**:

```
myImageView.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl){ (image, error, cacheType, url) in
    guard let image = image, cacheType == .none else { return }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let modifiedImage = myImageProcessor(image)
        SDWebImageManager.shared().saveImage(toCache: modifiedImage, for: imageUrl)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            myImageView.image = modifiedImage
            myImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @NeerajSonaro myImagePorcessor is any function which takes an image and returns another processed image.  I don't believe I need to update my answer. The "my..." is a pretty typical way of saying you need to fill in the blank here...