# SDWebImage: running a method BEFORE image is refreshed and placed

Tags: ios, image-processing, lazy-loading, sdwebimage

So before anything else, I found this:

[SDWebImage process images before caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928103/sdwebimage-process-images-before-caching)

which kind of helps but I really want to use `SDWebImage`, is there a way to process the images via a method outside of the class before completion?

To my understanding, the completion block in

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completed:(SDWebImageCompletedBlock)completedBlock
```

is run after the image is placed. I would like to run a method before the loaded image is placed.

Is there an easy way to do this?

thank you,

Answer (score 2):

reposting my answer from: [SDWebImage process images before caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928103/sdwebimage-process-images-before-caching/15393477#15393477)

SDWebImage developer Olivier Poitrey answered this question for me here.

You have to implement the SDWebImageManagerDelegate protocol and then set it as the shared manager's delegate like this:

SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.delegate = self;

using the imageManager:transformDownloadedImage:withURL: instance method.
More information.

Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: can u add some code sample you used for better clarification of answer?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Write your own routine that would [Use Asynchronous Image Caching Independently](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-asynchronous-image-downloader-independently), process the image, and then set the image view's `image` property. There are interesting permutations you'd have to worry about (e.g. if cell has been reused before the download has finished, you'd want to cancel the prior image download for that image view), so you need to be careful, but it's not too bad.
2. Probably easier, though, would be to write your own `UIImageView` category that is like the existing one for `SDWebImage` (`UIImageView+WebCache.m`), but introduce your own permutation of `setImageWithURL` which is just like the original, but offers a pre-process completion block, too.

I'd probably lean towards the latter, but both would work perfectly well

Comment: thanks for this Rob but the delegate method answer below worked as well.