# Xcode: get lighting information of a picture or predominant color

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, image, cgimage

I need to detect the predominant color or the ligthing of a picture.
It is possible? And how?

It is possibile to extract that data from a CGIMAGE?
Thanks

Comment: Use digicolor meter application.

Comment: Really cool advice, but I mean how can I do it "programmatically". Thanks

Comment: I am not much into graphics stuff. So from my knowlwdge..you need to trace all the pixels and keep on storing the REQUIRED color if found, "how you will come to know this pixel is predominant" is your logic

Answer (score 0):

Resize the image to 1x1 pixel. Use the category [UIImage+ColorAtPixel.h](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton/tree/master/UIImage+ColorAtPixel) to extract the value of the pixel. You can transform the CGImage to a UIImage with [imageWithCGImage:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

To extract the value of the pixel, the category creates a context (CGBitmapContextCreate) with a RGBA buffer of 4 char and draws the image there. Then it extracts the color from the 4 components (RGBA) of the image.

Comment: There are many around. For example, scale to 1x1 using http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658801/412916 and then get the color at 0,0 with http://stackoverflow.com/a/1262893/412916 calling UIColor *color = [[[self class] getRGBAsFromImage:roses atX:0 andY:0 count:1] objectAtIndex:0];