# UIButtonTypeCustom image deformed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

```
customBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,68,68)];
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dash_pulsante_attivo"];
[customBtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(triggerMeasurement) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:customBtn];
```

I'm building a custom button that should be using a `68x68` png for it's normal state.
But the image looks deformed: it should be a circle, but it display as an oval.
Any hint or suggestion why it is happening? Curiously, I've tried to swap with another circular png, `220x220`, and everything works as expected.

Comment: check the png size is 68x68 or not?? if size is ok means check whether you are changing this button frame in some other place of your code...

Comment: can you able to attach the screenshot??

Comment: check the image "dash_pulsante_attivo" resolution.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was a stupid error, my fault. I checked like 20 times if the images had the right size, but I was checking on the finder (not the one I imported in my project). The error was that I imported in my project the original image - that was bigger. Quite embarassing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this error happened, because of image size, check whether the image size is 68x68.

nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was a stupid error, my fault. I checked like 20 times if the images had the right size, but I was checking on the finder (not the one I imported in my project). The error was that I imported in my project the original image - that was bigger. Quite embarassing :)

Answer (score 0):

check the image `"dash_pulsante_attivo"` resolution. If it's less than 68*68 it supposed to get distorted. Higher resolution won't have distortion problem.

If you want resize your image programatically. You can do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658801/641062).