# Reduce Resolution UIImage/UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a UIImageView which contains an image with a high resolution. The problem is that the resolution of that image is too high to put into the imageView. The size of the imageView is 92 x 91 (so it's small). It contains an UIImage, whose resolution is too high so it looks ugly in the UIImageView.
So how can I reduce the resolution of that UIImage?

My code for the UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath]];
    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(212.0, 27, 92,91);
```

Comment: What is your definition of resolution?  It's often used as the number of pixels per unit.  It sounds like you define it as the dimensions of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658801

This will help you to resize your image according to your need

Add method to your code and call like this

```
UIImage *myImage =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];
UIImage *newImage =[UIImage imageWithImage:myImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(92,91)];
```

Comment: How can I implement that class method?

Comment: please find it in the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can resize an image using this method that returns a resized image :

```
 -(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    // Here pass new size you need
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: how do I implement this code with my UIImage?

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
     myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to downsize the image, which will reduce the resolution, make it easier to store. I actually wrote a class (building on some stuff from SO) that does just that. It's on my github, take a look:

https://github.com/pavlovonline/UIImageResizer

the main method is

```
-(UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image toSize:(CGFloat)size
```

so you give this method the size to which you want to downsize your image. If the height is greater than the width, it will auto-calculate the middle and give you a perfectly centered square. Same for width being greater than height. If you need an image that is not square, make your own adjustments.

so you'll get back a downsized UIImage which you can then put into your UIImageView. Save some memory too.