# How to resize image with small size from camera

Tags: iphone, image, camera, resize

Do you have anyway to resize image from camera to small size. I would like to resize image to 612 * 612 with disk size is less than 100KB. This will help me to show image on application faster.

Any advise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this post for help:

[The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

and check out Apple's documentation on UIImage

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)imageToCompress scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [imageToCompress drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Give your file name istead of getPath & call the above:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getPath];
UIImage *imageToPass = [self imageWithImage:img scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(612.0, 612.0)];
```

Comment: This [self imageWithImage:img scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(612.0, 612.0)] line will automatically call above method & resize image...

Comment: how is about image disk size ? it is less than 100KB with dimension 612 ?

Comment: it is so big, more than 800KB, it's loaded very slowly. Instagram can do this. I used Instagram app to take a picture, then share it on Facebook or Twitter, then I downloaded this image and checked its size. it's 72KB with that dimension.