# Is there any good example for IOS to get a picture without clip?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

When we get an image from the ios album by default it always gets clipped.

Whereas if we use the UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage, then it is too big.

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage*temp =[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```

Is there any good method to edit the Image without clipping it's range?

Comment: get the original image and [resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage) it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like that...

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage*temp =[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake("WIDTH", "HEIGHT");  <---- SET YOUR VALUES
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [temp drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* smaller = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

}