# Resize a tagged UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiimage

I am trying to figure out how to resize an UIImage that is loaded with a tag. I have successfully loaded three images and tagged them.

The following is the "touchesEnded" code that i am using to test this, it trigger the NSLogs so the code works. In the resize-test i would like to resize the UIImage tag=0 after it has been moved, which is why i have it in "touchesEnded".

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSLog(@">>> touchesEnded <<<");

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

endLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

switch ([touch view].tag) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"touchesEnded: 0");

        // Resize call here

        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"touchesEnded: 1");
        [[touch view] setCenter: CGPointMake(180, 400)];
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"touchesEnded: 2");
        [[touch view] setCenter: CGPointMake(10, 10)];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

I would like to call this method, which i think should work:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
```

}

*Source: [The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage) (Paul Lynch)*

This is how i add the UIImages:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSArray *cards = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"img1.png", @"img2.png", @"img3.png",nil];

int x = 0;

for (NSString *theCards in cards) {
    DragView *actualCards = [[DragView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:theCards]];
    actualCards.tag = x;
    NSLog(@"Tag: %i", x);
    x++;
    [self.view addSubview:actualCards];

}
}
```

Tag 1 and 2 is for other testing.

But i just do not get it to work using a UIImage that has a tag so i would like to ask for some help or directions how to call the function and change the size of the UIImage.

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @rdelmar I do not understand how to call the method using the tagged UIImages?

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your case 0: clause, touch.view will be the image with tag 0, so just call your resizing method with that view as the argument:

```
UIImage *resizedImage = [self  imageWithImage:(UIImage *)touch.view scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize];
```

You'll need to change the method to an instance method for this to work:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
```

Comment: i do get into trouble yet again with the following message "+[UIImage imageWithImage:scaledToSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xa74154
2013-07-14 06:49:28.320 DragTest4[23192:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIImage imageWithImage:scaledToSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xa74154'"

Comment: @PeterK, there's several ways to fix that. You could create a category on UIImage and put the imageWithImage:scaledToSize: method in there. The other way is to make it an instance method (rather than class). I've updated my answer to show that.

Comment: i still get the same problem. I believe that "(UIImage *)touch.view"  (the tag) is the problem as it works when i test with a direct reference to the image.

Comment: @PeterK, what's still the problem? What result are you seeing if you try my code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you ask how to get the image. 
From your code, you first need get the tagged view which is the DragView instance, and then you can get the image simply by setting the image as a property of DragView.