# how to resize image with CALayer

Tags: ios, calayer

I can resize an image in `UIImageView` using code like

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

in order to render the image in a layer, I use the following code but it didn't work

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
CALayer *layer = (id)backgroundImage.CGImage;
```

the image isn't resized as expected, so how to resize it correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

Comment: What about the CALayer frame? CALayer will by default stretch the image to its bounds.

Comment: but I need some parts of the image keep original