# Add an image instead of a title to my title in my UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7

I have the following code in my uiviewcontroller that is embed in a uinavigationcontroller.

In viewDidLoad:

```
[self addLogo];
```

Below:

```
- (void) addLogo
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logoblack.png"];
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    myImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1;

   self.navigationItem.titleView = myImageView;
}
```

The image I have is 434 by 434 but I want it to be 30 by 30. Instead it is streched and overtakes my < Back button in the navigation bar. Is there a scale method?

Comment: Why don't you scale and resize your image in preview application and add it with 30X30 frame - Don't think its complex

Comment: Yes I will do that, just wanting to learn more about iOS api

Comment: Did you try changing the contentMode of titleView. say to UIViewContentModeBottom.

Comment: use this to resize [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

so that the imageview will not be streched , and keep its aspect