# Remove back arrow in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

[image]

I want to incorporate a custom back button - I'm able to get the above result using

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-btn"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

but how do you remove the native blue button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all the answerers - found a simpler way of doing it...

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-btn"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonAction:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:nil];

-(void) backButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting you'll lose your pop swipe gesture with this method

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is doing something completely different.  You are setting the back button from the top controller, rather than the controller where it is actually going back to.  You would have to do this for any controller that was on top...

Answer (score 13):

Use the below code to hide the back arrow:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-btn"]
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                        target:nil
                                                                        action:nil];

if ([UINavigationBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setBackIndicatorImage:)]) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}
```

Comment: That removes all the arrows, but adds the "Back" text.

Comment: if you added the backbarbuttonitem, then it will not show any "Back" text

Answer (score 9):

In iOS7+ you can use navigationBar's `backIndicatorImage` and `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` to achieve the custom arrow that you want. Swift code below:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named:"button-backArrow18x15")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named:"button-backArrowMask18x15")
```

If you want to hide the "back" text you can set the `title` of the previous view to be an single space " " or use a custom `UIBarButtonItem` that doesn't have a title.

Comment: You probably need to use `UIImage(named: "back-arrow")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)` to render the original image.

Answer (score 4):

You can hide backbutton

```
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

To create custom leftbarbutton you can use this:

```
UIButton* someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[someButton setFrame:frame];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:@"youArroImageName" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
UIBarButtonItem* someBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:someBarButtonItem];
```

Comment: That hides it completely, I want to show the custom white arrow.

Comment: For that you have to create Custon LeftBarButton item. And set as left  bar button item.

Comment: I addded added code as well to create custom leftebarbuttonitem.

Answer (score 3):

Check this one:

```
    UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow.png"];
    UIButton *face = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    face.bounds = CGRectMake( 10, 0, faceImage.size.width, faceImage.size.height );
    [face addTarget:self action:@selector(handleBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [face setImage:faceImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:face];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:nil];


  -(IBAction)handleBack:(id)sender
  {
     //    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```

Comment: It's actually simpler than that I found, see my answer

Comment: @daidai i taken as customizeview  so you can set it frame or bound also but in your code we didn't set it.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 (if you just want to hide it)

```
let mask = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = mask
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = mask
```

Comment: That does work great as long as iOS13+ `UINavigationBarAppearance` is not used for styling, which immediately reverts the workaround. Unfortunately I haven't found a way around that and I did try various approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try with the Custom UIButton :

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0f, 40.0f)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEN:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-btn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBtn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the exact same problem, here's what I ended up doing:

```
// First set the back button text to an empty string
viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = 
     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
          target:nil 
          action:nil];

// Set the back-indicator image to the custom image (scaled to 20x20)
UIImage *img = [MyUtils imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:img];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:img];

// Set the tint color to WHITE
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Here's the image-scaling method:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Credit for the scaling method above goes to [Paul Lynch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221617/paul-lynch) on this SO question: ([The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage))