# Swift - Help Converting from Objective C Syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to replace the `UINavigationController` `BackBarButtonItem` with a custom image, and I would like there to be no back icon like it's currently doing here:

[image]

I'm taking this picture from another stack post, but something similar is happening with mine

The solution to this was listed here: [Remove back arrow in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535131/remove-back-arrow-in-ios7)

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-btn"]
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                        target:nil
                                                                        action:nil];

if ([UINavigationBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setBackIndicatorImage:)]) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}
```

The problem is I'm having trouble converting this code to Swift. If anybody could help me that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421769/how-to-replace-customize-back-button-image-in-storyboard-navigationcontroller or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936296/custom-back-button-with-image

Comment: Thanks @Saavaj. According to the second link, they're doing it globally. Do I have to do it globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting swipe back feature :
First set delegate in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

And then disable gesture when pushing:

```
override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
}
```

And enable in `viewDidDisappear`:

```
self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
//Hide Default Back Button First
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);

//Your code to show back button
    let backButton = UIButton()
    backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), forState: .Normal)
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("action"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    rightBarButton.customView = backButton
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = rightBarButton

//Back Button Action

func action()
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

[Or you can refer one of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022780/uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code  in swift 3 :

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setBackButton()
    }

    func setBackButton() {
        let backImage = UIImage(named:"back_icon") as UIImage!
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(BaseViewController.viewWillDisappearC) )

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    }

    func viewWillDisappearC() {
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't contain the swipe back feature then

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in swift 2.2 (xocde 7.3) :

class BaseViewController: UIViewController  {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setBackButton()
}

func setBackButton() {
    let backImage = UIImage(named:"back_icon") as UIImage!
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImage, style:UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(BaseViewController.viewWillDisappearC) )
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}

func viewWillDisappearC() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't contain the swipe back feature then