# Resize dimensions of a UIImage and save in an NSData

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata, dimensions

I want to resize a `UIImage` (height and width) and store it in a `NSData` with new measures. Example:

```
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:compression orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]
```

This does not preserve the dimensions when converted to `NSData`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scale parameter does something else than resizing image. To give real life example - scale is involved when you load retina images. In that case, image dimensions are halved, while amount of data (and thus the actual dimensions) are not. This is just a clever way to provide nice compatibility between retina/nonretina devices.

What you need is to create smaller CGContext and redraw an image. There should be plenty of examples even in SO. For example here: [The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)