# Colour Variation in images used in Imageview

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an imageview in my app and I set the image of that imageview using interface builder.

This is my problem:

**The actual image is this**

[image: The actual image is this]

**But in simulator its color have a variation and displays this**

[image: But in simulator its color have a variation and displays this]

Please not the colour variation in it. 
What may be the reason?Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this, the **size different** between `your image` and `Your ImageView`. Actually, Here your image is **stretched** , that's why, It appear like this. You can solve this problem by resizing your image with code. [Use this link to resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

Comment: No the sizes are same,I have checked it the Images I added here have different size because of the size variation of screenshot

Comment: @LML otherwise no idea man. Double check with your image name, You may missed that some time.

Comment: Same I can see my correct image in storyboard as well but when in simulator its colour get changed

Comment: Did you check with device? One doubt. Is your xib size differ from simulator size (ie 3.5" and 4")?

Comment: Didn't check in device. No its same 4"