# Scale an image to a given NSData byte size - PNG compression

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, compression, core-graphics

If I have a UIImage and I convert is to NSData I can see how many bytes it is.

If I have a variable `requiredSize` and I want to set that UIImage to a certain length and width so that when it is rendered as a PNG-file NSData `UIImagePNGRepresentation();` it is a certain byte-size (`requiredSize`). How do I go about doing this.

---

I know how to get the current byte size `[NSData length];`

---

And I know how to downscale a UIImage (If there's a better way please tell me)

```
    //UIImage *tempImage = whateverTheImagePointerIs;

    int tempWidth = tempImage.size.width/2;//50% width of original
    int tempHeight = tempImage.size.height/2;//50% height of original
    UIImageView *tempImageRender = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tempWidth, tempHeight)];

    tempImageRender.image = tempImage;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tempImageRender.bounds.size, tempImageRender.opaque, 1.0);
    [tempImageRender.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *tempFinalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

---

But when I scale it by 50% on width and 50% on height (25% net-total) the final bytes of the new rendered scaled image (when converted to PNG using `UIImagePNGRepresentation();`) is not 25% of the original bytes... it seems to just be random (I'm sure this is happening because PNG compression algorithms change with image quality/size.)

---

Is there no way to resize an image to a given byte size?

Comment: @rmaddy What you posted uses a recursive formula that resizes then renders an image with a while-loop until it is beneath a certain size. For one this is incredibly slow, for two this also doesn't answer my question.. this could get me a .4mB file when I need a .6mB file. I want to set a file size, not recursively compress until I've gone below a "maximum".

Comment: There is no direct way to get what you want. There is no method that says "scale the image so the resulting PNG data will be X bytes".

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Since PNG compression doesn't scale with image size, there's no way to do it that isn't iterative.

Comment: @David Do either of you know an image format that doesn't compress (unlike PNG) that I can render in Objective-C as NSData that way I don't have to deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw If you're limited to how many bytes you can upload, why would you want to use a non-compressing storage format?

Comment: @David I'm not limited to how many bytes I can use... I need to have the file size an exact number of bytes (or very close at least)

Comment: If your goal is to generate an image file with the most consistent/predictable size, try something like BMP or just raw image data.  Unfortunately, neither of those can be directly generated by iOS.

Answer (score -1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage) for how to scale an image fairly effectively:

As you've discovered, there really isn't a direct correlation between image size and data size when compressed, you'll just have to do it iteratively:

```
-(NSData*)pngRepresentationWithMaxSize:(NSInteger)maxSize
{
    UIImage*    image = self;

    while(1)
    {
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        if(data.length < maxSize)
            return data;
        CGSize  size = image.size;

        image = [UIImage imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(image.size.width / 2., image.size.height / 2.)];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Note that I assume you change the referenced scaling code to be a category method on UIImage and put the method above into a UIImage category as well.

Comment: I'm confused what `while(1){` does... wouldn't that loop forever?

Comment: The `return` breaks the loop when the condition is met.

Comment: It loops until `if(data.length < maxSize)` is true.  Probably ought to put more boundary checking in, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader.