# How to change UIBarButtonItem size programmatically?

Tags: uiview, frame, uibarbuttonitem

```
UIBarButtonItem *adminBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                          initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"779-users"] 
                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                          target:self 
                                          action:@selector(adminButtonTouched)];
```

I tried to assign a new frame to `adminBarButtonItem.customView.frame`, it didn't work.

Expect for `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aView]`, is there anyway to change the size of `UIBarButtonItem`?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation where I needed to resize a custom image to fit alongside another system bar button item. The key is to resize the image itself before I use it in UIBarButtonItem's initWithImage method.

For how to resize that UIImage, follow this link [The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

Another pitfall is the tintColor of the custom button item. I used

```
myButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myImage];
```

to get around the blue tint that covers up my image (iOS8), but I suspect there exists a more kosher way. If anybody knows, please enlighten me.