# UIImage scaled on iPhone 6Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimage

In my app, I have a method that transforms a `UIView` into a `UIImage`. It works fine on every device, except on the iPhone 6 plus, which has a higher pixel density.

I am creating the `selectionIndicatorImage` for my `UITabBar` by transforming a grey view into a `UIImage`. I know this is probably not the best practice in this scenario but anyway I need this method working fine for other things on the application.

This is my `UIImage` initializer:

```
convenience init?(view: UIView) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

    var img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.init(CGImage: img.CGImage)
}
```

This generates the following results:

iPhone 6 Plus

[image: iPhone 6 Plus]

iPhone 6

[image: iPhone 6]

Any thoughts?

Cheers

Comment: try using clipsToBounds =YES property

Comment: Thanks @muku but that doesn't solve my problem. I need the `UIImage` to be properly scaled, not clipped

Answer (score 0):

//Look For Line.Hope this helps you

"The simplest way is to set the frame of your UIImageView and set the contentMode to one of the "
[The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

Comment: Should I need to resize it? I though that setting the scale to 0.0 on `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` would make it resize to the proper size for the screen

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are calculating tabBarFrame in viewDidLoad method, when tab bar is not created yet, the frame property will give you wrong results. You need to move your code in viewDidAppear method or if you want to do your calcuation earlier you can also move it in viewWillAppear but call `tabBar.layoutIfNeeded()` first

Comment: In my case, frame is the same on `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`. Also, it works on the iPhone 6