# Insets to UIImageView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, storyboard

I would like to achieve :

- Scale to fill mode of image view
- Insets to `UIImageView` so that image
  does not meet the edges of the `UIImageView`

Bottomline: I want to increase the touch area of the `UIImageView` without stretching the image beyond certain size.

Is it possible through storyboard ? If not can anyone tell how to do it programmatically ?

I can achieve similar functionality through a `UIButton` and setting image inset through storyboard but I can't find any such thing with `UIImageView`.

Comment: Are you considering changing the size of the image while in runtime without actually affecting the original image? will that do?

Comment: That would change the scale and pixelate your image if your imageview is low, instead there is a turnaround which you can try, if u are willing to reconsider i can post an answer

Comment: you can post I'll see if it works ..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using the method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage) :

```
UIImage *image= [MyUtil imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(80, 80)];

UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[imgView setImage:image];
```

Now your insets become 100-80 i.e. 20 .

This is a workaround to provide insets to an UIImageView. Better answers are welcomed.

Answer (score 91):

You can add inset to `UIImage` instead of `UIImageView`.

**Swift 4**

```
let imageView = UIImageView() 
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "example")?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: -4, left: 0, bottom: -4, right: 0))
```

Comment: I corrected the syntax but this actually doesn't work

Comment: Works super well. I found I had to put negative insets to make my image smaller though.

Comment: Looks good on paper, but has no effect for me, whether negative or positive values for the `UIEdgeInset` arguments. And yes, I'm using contentMode `.scaleAspectFill`.

Comment: I just tested it again, it appears it has no effect when you are setting `imageView` frame manually. It works when `imageView` is set using auto layout.

Comment: I'm using constraints.

Comment: This will change the UIImageView's constraints.

Comment: I ran in the problem that this solution didnt work for me. The problem was that my image had top, bottom, trailing and leading constrains to its parent. The fix was to have only "align center x" and "align center y" contains to be available for this imageView. So the imageView can compute its own instrict size, taking the insets into count.

Comment: This has strange behavior for my use case. I wanted a rounded grey square background (48px) with an inset image in the center (24px). I was using constraints for layout. For some reason this messes with the corner radius and background size. Would recommend just using a UIView and embedded UIImageView rather than messing with this property.

Answer (score 28):

It looks like you want to have a touchable imageView, so why not using an UIButton with image and imageEdgeInsets?

```
UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[b setFrame:someFrame];
[b setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
b.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
[b addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Awesome I love the idea of using button to add insets functionality to the image. +1

Comment: This works fine until iOS changes the look/feel of buttons again and suddenly puts borders or backgrounds in them so they don't just look like unadorned images anymore.

Comment: definitely a solution.  nice!

Answer (score 26):

My Code

- minus inset: smaller image
- plus inset: larger image

**Swift4**

```
private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let insetValue: CGFloat = -8
    view.image = image.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: insetValue, left: insetValue, bottom: insetValue, right: insetValue))
    return view
}()
```

Answer (score 21):

### Do not suffer, try this:

After trying for a while I found this solution:

```
extension UIImage {

    func withInset(_ insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage? {
        let cgSize = CGSize(width: self.size.width + insets.left * self.scale + insets.right * self.scale,
                            height: self.size.height + insets.top * self.scale + insets.bottom * self.scale)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cgSize, false, self.scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

        let origin = CGPoint(x: insets.left * self.scale, y: insets.top * self.scale)
        self.draw(at: origin)

        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.withRenderingMode(self.renderingMode)
    }
}
```

#### Usage example:

```
let margin:CGFloat = 16
self.imageView.image = image?.withInset(UIEdgeInsets(top: margin, left: margin, bottom: margin, right: margin))
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/cc79170422236d027b2b)

Comment: All the answers here and this was the only one that worked. Thanks.

Comment: this work, but removing `* self.scale` is better

Answer (score 10):

One option is to use `withAlignmentRectInsets`, but it doesn't work with the layer border.

Another way is to use `resizableImage(withCapInsets: resizingMode: .stretch)` where you'd want to use positive inset values for smaller images.

Sample code:

```
private func setupQRImageView() -> UIImageView {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.layer.borderColor = Default.imageBorderColor.cgColor
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
    let imageInset: CGFloat = 8.0
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "QR")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: imageInset, left: imageInset, bottom: imageInset, right: imageInset), resizingMode: .stretch)
    return imageView
}
```

Produces the following result:

[image: UIImageView with a border and padded inset]

Answer (score 5):

You can add a `UIView` first and then you add your `UIImageView` inside the `UIView` with a padding of whatever you like, and if you want your gesture to get affected only in `UIImageView`, make it UserInteractionEnable to yes or if you want the gesture to be in the whole then you can add the gesture to the whole `UIView`

Answer (score 5):

Try work around with UIImage within UIView like this ;

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Draw the UIImage inside an UIView and use autolayout to constrain UIImage to size you want

Comment: Thanks for this. The usual solutions were just causing loads of problems, this works as desired.