# why UITableViewCell AccessoryView: Setting accessoryView equal to UIImageView infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a custom UITableView that has 2 types of cells. One cell is just set to toggle between a normal accessory of type checkmark. Another cell is set to have a custom image as the accessory type. When selected that accessory image changes to its opposite type, showing an "Selected" or "Unselected" message.

```
 if (self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
                cell.accessoryView = self.selectedImageView;
            }else
                cell.accessoryView = self.unSelectedImageView;
```

If it matters the UIImageViews are initialized as follows:

```
-(UIImageView *)selectedImageView
{
    if (!_selectedImageView) {
        _selectedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Check"]];
    }
    return _selectedImageView;
}
-(UIImageView *)unSelectedImageView
{
    if (!_unSelectedImageView) {
        _unSelectedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noCheck"]];
    }
    return _unSelectedImageView;
}
```

i saw someone answer this question:[UITableCell AccessoryView: Setting accessoryView equal to UIImageView infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624404/uitablecell-accessoryview-setting-accessoryview-equal-to-uiimageview-infinite-l)

he said :I have figured out the answer on my own but here it is for anyone else who needs it: UIImageViews cannot be shared so a different instantiation of each UIImageView is required for each visible cell. Now you know.

but i don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UIView` can only be a subview of one parent view, so once you have added your `UIImageView` to one cell you can't add it to any others.

`UIImage` doesn't have this limitation, so you can modify your code to have `selectedImage` and `unSelectedImage` methods along the lines of what you have now or even modify your current methods so that they return a new UIImageView each time.