# Image overlapping ui navigation bar swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I currently have in image in a nav bar but it's overlapping the edge:[image: overlap]

Here is the code I use in viewDidLoad:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "holy-grail-pub-logo-header-logo")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

I've tried setting the position manually using CGRECT but it wasn't changing anything:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -30, width: 100, height: 60))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    let logo = UIImage(named: "holy-grail-pub-logo-header-logo")
    imageView.image = logo
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried applying the sizeToFit() method? i.e. imageView.sizeToFit()

Answer (score 0):

Basically I hope you need to adjust the `edgeInsets` for your `imageView` which we cannot do directly on `UIImageView` as of now.

Using the method given [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

I did convert it to Swift(for your ref):

```
extension UIImage {

class func imageWith(image: UIImage, scaledToSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
        // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
        // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scaledToSize, false, 0.0)
        image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, scaledToSize.width, scaledToSize.height))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Using above method:

```
let image = UIImage.imageWith(UIImage(named: "holy-grail-pub-logo-header-logo")!, scaledToSize: CGSizeMake(80,80))
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = image
```

Now your `insets` become 100-80 i.e. 20. I guess this workaround would help you fixing your issue. Try this and let us know if it works.

Comment: I tried adding the code to the project but now the image doesn't appear at all in the nav bar.

Comment: Did you miss this line at the end?
`self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView`