# How to make a gif image smaller

Tags: ios, objective-c, gif

I have got a problem when I uploaded a gif image to the server, I have to make the gif image smaller and guarantee that the server received a gif image , I just out of mind.

Comment: Are you facing problem in uploading larger gif images or the gif images are not  uploading in the server at all?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2658738/1457385

Comment: so what is your problem,
 how to reduce the size or upload the image as huge gif image, as it is ?

Comment: I have find out the Terms of settlement ，thank u all .