# Stop repeating UIImage background pattern image - Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uiimage

I'm using swipe to delete in UITableView. In swipe I need to add image. When I add image it repeats. How to stop repeating

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
            self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView!(self.tableView, commit: .delete, forRowAt: indexPath)
            return
        }

        deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "favourite_delete"))
        deleteButton.title = ""
            return [deleteButton]
}
```

Problem

[image]

What I need

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, as you might have guessed, is here:

```
deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "favourite_delete"))
```

You are creating a `UIColor` using the `(patternImage:)` initializer. This means that the image will be repeated (See the word "pattern"?).

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621933-init):

> You can use pattern colors to set the fill or stroke color just as you would a solid color. **During drawing, the image in the pattern color is tiled as necessary to cover the given area.**

To solve this, you can resize your image so that it fits the frame of the button programmatically. See [The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

Alternatively, use [MGSwipeTableViewCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell), it allows you to put images on swipe buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  resizeWithWidth():

```
let placeHolderImage = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle.fill")!.resizeWithWidth(width: 40)!
color = UIColor(patternImage: placeHolderImage)
```