# How to fit background image of label to the frame size of a label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "na72.png")!)
```

(UILABEL)

How to fit background image of label to the frame size of a label?
I should use 'self.backgroundColor = UIColor(~~)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are creating a `UIColor` using a `patternimage`, it is designed to create a tile pattern.

To work around this, you can resize your image to match the size of the frame of your label manually, or by using a function (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24498221/11163986)), then use your resized image as your `patternimage`.

Example using the above function:

```
let image = imageWithImage(image: UIImage(named: "na72.png")!, scaledToSize: label.frame.size)
label.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

This issue was also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709819/stop-repeating-uiimage-background-pattern-image-swift)