# Scale incorrect with resize UIImage and export to jpeg

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, scale

Hello I have the following function to save a jpg image with a scale factor

```
- (UIImage*) pixelBufferToUIImage:(CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBuffer
{
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

    CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                             createCGImage:ciImage
                             fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer),
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))];
    UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:videoImage scale:(1/scale_factor) orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    CGImageRelease(videoImage);
    return uiImage;
}
```

I call this method like so,

```
NSData* image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self pixelBufferToUIImage:frame.capturedImage], 0.8);
[image writeToFile:[self getFilePathWith:folderName and:@"image.jpg"] atomically:NO];
```

If I call the save with a `scale_factor = 1.0f` which is the original resolution I get a `1280x720` image

However, I want to half the image size. I tried setting `scale_factor = 0.5f and 2.0f` Both did not work and I get the jpg's size as `1280x720`

Could anyone point out my mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says that the `scale` will change what the **`size`** property reports. It does not change the image's pixel data. The internal representation of the `UIImage` still has the same dimensions.

> **scale**
>  The scale factor to use when interpreting the image data.
>   Specifying a scale factor of 1.0 results in an image whose size
>   matches the pixel-based dimensions of the image. Applying a different
>   scale factor changes the size of the image as reported by the size
>   property.

To scale your image you need to do the scaling yourself.

[Have a look here how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658801/4543629)

So you could do it like this. Put the method in the link in your class, then add the scaling call before converting your image to JPEG.

```
CGFloat newScale = 0.5;
UIImage *uiImage = [self pixelBufferToUIImage:frame.capturedImage];
uiImage = [YourClass imageWithImage:uiImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(uiImage.size.width * newScale, uiImage.size.height * newScale)];
NSData* image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uiImage, 0.8);
[image writeToFile:[self getFilePathWith:folderName and:@"image.jpg"] atomically:NO];
```