# Give inset to UIImageView before setting Its frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an `UITextField` component which has an icon on the right side of it. Icon is just an `UIImageView`. I'm trying to give inset to `UIImageView` with below code

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "example")?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: -4, left: 0, bottom: -4, right: 0))
```

However, It doesn't work cuz It's frame hasn't been set when setting Its' Image. I'm giving Its frame with below code;

```
iconImageView.frame = CGRect(
            x: bounds.size.width - iconWidth - iconMarginLeft,
            y: bounds.size.height - textHeight() - iconMarginBottom,
            width: iconWidth,
            height: textHeight()
        )
```

and how I setup `UIImageView`

```
fileprivate func createIconImageView() {
    let iconImageView = UIImageView()
    iconImageView.backgroundColor = .clear
    iconImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iconImageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
    if (hasToolTip) {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(toolTipTapped(_:)))
        iconImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        iconImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let image = UIImage(named: "infotooltip")
        image?.accessibilityIdentifier = "tooltipImage"
        iconImageView.image = image!
        changeIconAlphaToOne()
        self.iconImageView = iconImageView
    } else {
       self.iconImageView = iconImageView
        changeIconAlphaToZero()
    }
    addSubview(iconImageView)
}
```

**My problem** is that, I need to give `UIEdgeInset` to the image. However, because I'm trying to give it before setting the frame, It doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

I also try to resize the image by referencing below post but doesn't work for me. I also DO NOT want to put it inside a content view which will make my component class more complicated.
[The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

Comment: Don't know the purpose of what you are doing, but maybe you could use `UITextField.rightView` for that?

Comment: i suggest you to wrap imageView in UIView and set constraints

Comment: I can successfully add the icon. Just need insets.

Comment: @SPatel As I mentioned in question, I'm looking for a different answer cuz It will make component more complicated.

Comment: image inset is not possible

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EsYeJ3ui

Comment: Sorry I can't open pastebin

Comment: This would be really really easy with interface builder and constraints.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that whole component (created with 3 different class) incl placeholder, texts, icon, error message and icon width is calculating and not using auto layout.