# Swift - Button Image size is not downscaling

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Swift is not downscaling my image to fit to AspectFit and is at pre-downscaled size. Links to pictures are provided.

```
@objc private func didDoubleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let likedImage = UIImage(named: "likedImage")
        likeButton.setImage(likedImage, for: .normal)
        likeButton.contentMode = .center //344 436 50 50
        likeButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
```

before double tapping

[image]

after double tapping

[image]

Comment: See how to resize UIImage here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867644/7877857

Comment: Make sure you have added height and width constraint to button. And change `Style` to `Default` from Attribute inspector for `UIButton`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the size of with and height then

just add the imageEdgeInsets

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```